# How is OptionsPattern[] defined? Can I replicate this?

Tags: function-construction, options

I am writing several functions which all take similar input parameters (a complicated nested list structure). Is there some way for me to define a pattern that can be used in multiple places and allows me to extract the individual parameters?

(I find `OptionsPattern[]` interesting because its definition isn't really visible but somehow `OptionValues[]` is able to extract information from it.)

Comment: Why not use `Options` then?

Comment: I don't really want Options — specifying `->` rules for each argument will be even messier than the current definition using named patterns like `var_`. I just want a way to decrease the number of times I have the whole argument list written out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you can do is to create a strong type. I have described one way to do it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/how-to-create-strong-types/4645#4645), and this is also described at length in the Roman Maeder's book "Programming in Mathematica" (which is *the* original reference).

One other thing which comes to mind is the following: you can name the pattern, and use the alias for it, for example as follows:

```
ptrn = {a_, b : {c_Integer, d_Integer}, e_}
f[pt : ptrn] := {a, b, c, d, e}
```

Then, you get

```
?f
Global`f
f[pt:{a_,b:{c_Integer,d_Integer},e_}]:={a,b,c,d,e}
```

So the function ends up being the same as if you used the full pattern directly. You can use it to check that:

```
f[{1,{2,3},4}]

(* {1,{2,3},2,3,4} *)
```

Even though this works, I would probably take the strong type route, since with the second option it is less obvious from the code which defines `f` what those letters stand for, and easier to make a mistake.

As for the `OptionsPattern`, it seems to be a rather magical construct. I gave a very schematic possible implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335897/mathematica-how-is-optionvalue-implemented/5336802#5336802), but I am not proud of it. I think it is wired quite deeply and it is hard to implement it cleanly with the top-level code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why did you use `pt` and `b` and not `pt_` and `b_`? I was under the impression that `pt : ptrn` would just specify a default value; is something else happening here?

Comment: @jtbandes `:` is used for both `Pattern` and `Optional` (search for `:` in the docs). You're thinking of the latter usage. A simple way to distinguish between the two is as follows: `Pattern` usage has the structure `name : pattern` whereas `Optional` usage has the structure `pattern : value`. So `x : _foo` is pattern and `x_ : foo` is optional.

Comment: @jtbandes `pt:ptrn` represents the pattern object `ptrn` given the name `pt`. So `ptrn` defines the form of `pt`.

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica* argument sequences are just expressions, so they can be named and referenced by name just like other expressions. Suppose you wanted use the fairly complicated argument pattern

```
argPattern = 
   Sequence[data : {Except[_Complex, _?NumberQ] ..}, 
      lbls : {_String, _String} : {"", ""}];
```

as the formal argument list of more than one function, then all you need do is use the name `argPattern` in each function definition, like so:

```
stdPlot[argPattern] := ListPlot[data, AxesLabel -> lbls, Filling -> Axis]

logPlot[argPattern] := ListLogPlot[data, AxesLabel -> lbls, Filling -> Axis]
```

Both functions will accept arguments according to the pattern:

```
data1 = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, 10];
stdPlot[data1, {"n", "Output"}]
```

[image]

```
data2 = RandomInteger[{0, 10^5}, 10];
logPlot[data2, {"n", "Output"}]
```

[image]