# Ways to protect certain parts of expressions

Tags: programming, syntax

I am currently working on a quantum mechanics problem where I try to find equations that relate different states of a many-body system. The states are described by sets of pairs of integers, like `list1 = {{0,0},{0,1},{1,-1},{3,-3}}`. There is a very expensive and complicated function `listToPoly[li_List]` that turn such lists into polynomials. It turns out that many seemingly different lists can produce the same polynomial, or that sets of lists produce sets of polynomials that are linearly dependent. I have found a way to determine some of these dependencies without using `listToPoly` but I would like some help implementing it.

What I want to accomplish is a way to represent these lists in a way that I can **both** act on them with functions that manipulate their list structure, e.g.,

```
func1[li_List,k_] := Transpose[{#1+k, #2}]& @@ Transpose[li]
```

**and** programmatically generate and solve the equations that represent the linear dependences. Say I have three lists:

```
l1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}
l2 = {{0, 0}, {0, 2}}
l3 = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}
```

and I find out that their corresponding polynomials `p1, p2, p3` would satisfy

```
2*p1 - 3*p2 + p3 == 0
```

I would like to be able to generate such equations using the lists (I don't want to invoke `listToPoly`), but then I need to prevent evaluation like

```
2*l1 - 3*l2 + l3 = {{0, 1}, {0, -2}}
```

Even combining the two things, it would be nice to be able to define something like

```
lindep[li_List, kmax_] := Sum[(-1)^k * func1[li, k], {k, kmax}] == 0
```

and then evaluate

```
lindep[{{0,0},{0,1}}, 2]
```

to get

> ```
> - {{1,0},{1,1}} + {{2,0},{2,1}} == 0
> ```

There are probably lots of ways to do this, like:

- Using `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`
- Adding or replacing a custom head and defining functions to act on object with that head
- Using `ToString` and `ToExpression` back and forth
- etc.

#### Question

What would you guys choose? Any clear (dis)advantages to any particular method? I realize I am basically asking "how to handle custom objects", but I thought giving the context would make it easier to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Related: [(4636)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4636/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I realize I am basically asking "how to handle custom objects", but I thought giving the context would make it easier to point me in the right direction.

It seems that you are.  I believe the most natural way to do that in *Mathematica* is to use a custom head.  I'll use `obj` for my examples.

First you might define a pattern for your custom object:

```
p0 = obj[{{_, _} ..}];
```

Then define a new `func1` (I'll call `fn1`) referencing that pattern:

```
fn1[li : p0, k_] := MapAt[# + k &, li, {1, All, 1}]
```

And `lindep`:

```
lindep[li : p0, kmax_] := Sum[(-1)^k*fn1[li, k], {k, kmax}] == 0
```

We can define a [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to style `obj` expressions as plain lists:

```
Format[x : p0] := Interpretation[First @ x, x]
```

Finally:

```
lindep[obj[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 2]
```

> ```
> -{{1, 0}, {1, 1}} + {{2, 0}, {2, 1}} == 0
> ```

Comment: Thanks, using a custom head was my hunch. Also, using Format and Interpretation this way was new to me, cool! If I only plan on using the head `obj` for these lists, would there be any difference between your suggestion, and not defining `p0` but simply defining functions like `fn1[li_obj, k_]`?

Comment: @Marius Don't be too quick to Accept an answer. (But thank you.)  You can use `li_obj` if you like and it will be somewhat faster if applied a lot, but the longer pattern will make sure the data is not malformed.  Regarding `Format` I remembered after posting that I probably should have used `MakeBoxes` instead; please see: [(4112299)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112299/618728)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard First off, this solution is very helpful. In your example, have you noticed that if you assign the lindep function to a variable `x = lindep[obj[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 2]` that `?x` results in an error with infinite recursion? Are there some additional changes that can be made to fix this?

Comment: @Adam I was not able to reproduce that problem (v10.1.0 under Windows 7) but I think it may be caused by my use of `Format` instead of `MakeBoxes`, out of laziness.  See [(4119830)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4119830/618728).