# Custom Head for Encapsulation

Tags: data-structures, object-oriented, head

Often when I'm writing a project in Mathematica, the number of arguments I must provide to functions spins out of control.

I need a sort of object-oriented encapsulation approach. I've already had a go at doing this in Java, and now believe than an object-oriented language is not well suited to my needs.

### Example:

Here I fetch data for the geodesic of a test particle in a pseudo-Riemannian manifold. The user must supply the metric in matrix form, the initial positions and velocities, and other miscellaneous things:

```
NGeodesicData[( {
    {(1 - (1/#2)) &, 0 &, 0 &},
    {0 &, -(1 - 1/#2)^-1 &, 0 &},       (*Matrix of real functions*)
    {0 &, 0 &, (-#2^2) &}
   } ) , 
    {{0, 50, 0.}, {Null, 0., .0008}},   (*Initial position and velocity*)
    {1, True, True},                    (*Miscellaneous*)
  2500, .01, 1]                         (*Numerical integration settings*)
```

All of these arguments are necessary, and I would like to structure them in a more manageable format.

---

Specifically, I would like a head called `TangentVector` which consists of:

1. An **n x n** matrix of real functions of **n** variables each. (The matrix of real functions)
2. A list of two **n**-dimensional vectors. (the initial position and velocity; a tangent vector)

I am used to object-oriented languages where I can **program a constructor in which I can perform checks, throw exceptions or warnings if I need to, and store a couple of fields based on the input**. Basically, I'm looking to do the same thing here.

---

How can I create such a `TangentVector` structure, and make a constructor for it?

I believe I have already found a solution to complicated pattern-matching (on the inputs to the constructor) [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html).

Comment: So are you after the pattern for matching? Or a OO-implementation? Going with standard *Mathematica* paradigms might be less hassle (there are several threads on OO around though).

Comment: @YvesKlett - I have solved the pattern-matching problem; the main thing is that I need a constructor which can take input (I know how to do the pattern matching) and create a `TangentVector` structure based on that. The reason that I want this structure is so that other functions can take in `TangentVector`s as inputs. The best way I know of to do this is to create a custom head. I will be happy with any encapsulation approach though.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(4636)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4636/121),
[(16869)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16869/121), [(33884)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33884/121),
[(73960)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73960/121)

Comment: Suggest you look at Association

Comment: You might find some of answers to [this question[(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/990/3066) of interest, although I think the addition of Association in V10 makes some the answers obsolescent.