# How to implement shared data structures?

Tags: data-structures, object-oriented

If I have a shared data structure like you would find in nested C structs, how would I best implement that in Mathematica?

I have some "object-oriented" code I would like to port to Mathematica. It's not really objected-oriented, except in the sense that there are parent objects and child objects inherit various fields from a common parent. So, for example, there is MovingObject which has velocity, heading, x_position, y_position, etc., and then there are various classes that inherit these common fields. So, you might have a car object, boat object, plane object, etc, all of which extend MovingObject.

The shared methods are non-existent or trivial, so the main thing is just how to share the movement-related data fields.

Comment: In this case, perhaps the most economical way would be to use `Association`-s with a field called `"Type"` (or just `Type`), possibly wrapped in inert symbol(s) if you need to use `UpValues` and overload some methods, or if you need mutability. Have a look at [this example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110317/81) for such a use, for both mutable and immutable case.