# How to feed parameters obtained from direct 3D manipulation back into Manipulate's controls?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, dynamic, graphics3d

Here's a simple example of using `Manipulate` to interactively change the viewer's point-of-view for a 3D graphics object:

```
Manipulate[
 Framed[
  Graphics3D[{PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"]},
   ViewPoint -> 
    3.0 {Cos[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], 
      Sin[\[Phi]]},
   ViewAngle -> 0.5,
   ImageSize -> 200
   ],
  FrameStyle -> LightGray],
 {{\[Theta], 1.0}, 0, 2 \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{\[Phi],   0.5}, 0,   \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

The resulting widget looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Moving the widget's sliders does rotate the point-of-view, but a similar effect can be achieved by "directly" rotating the 3D image (i.e. "dragging" over the object's image with the cursor), like one can do with any other 3D graphics object in *Mathematica*.  If one does this to the 3D object displayed within the widget, then the slider controls stop working.

How can I modify this widget so that such direct manipulations, instead of disabling the sliders, actually *update* their values?

(The net effect would be to have *two* complementary ways to modify the point-of-view: just as the sliders give control over the image's point-of-view, any modification of this point-of-view by some other channel should be instantaneously reflected in the values of the sliders.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) is the key.  The code does not keep track of `ViewVertical`, which will change as the graphics are rotated by the mouse.  See the references at the end for some of the answers where I used this technique.

```
Manipulate[
 Framed[Graphics3D[{PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"]}, 
   ViewPoint -> 
    Dynamic[3.0 {Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]},
      (θ = Mod[ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]], 2 Pi];
       ϕ = ArcTan[Norm[#[[1 ;; 2]]], #[[3]]]) &],
   ViewAngle -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 200], FrameStyle -> LightGray],
 {{θ, 1.0}, 0, 2 π, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ϕ, 0.5}, -π/2, π/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> None]
```

I did something similar here: [Synchronizing the camera view of multiple Image3D panels within a Manipulate interface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71653/synchronizing-the-camera-view-of-multiple-image3d-panels-within-a-manipulate-int/71942#71942)

See also my answer to [Transparent Cylinder with Dashed Edges only](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/transparent-cylinder-with-dashed-edges-only/20993#20993), in which the control uses

```
ViewVector -> Dynamic[viewVec], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vert]
```

to interact with the rotation of 3D graphics.

In [How can I create a fountain effect?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18508/how-can-i-create-a-fountain-effect/18545#18545), I used a dynamic `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` to calculate the arc of water spraying out of a hose.