# Randomly assigning color to Graphics3D objects?

Tags: graphics3d, color, random

I have a set of Graphics3D primitives (here, spheres) which I would like to assign either:

1. One of a subset of colors, e.g. {Green, Red}
2. A random color over some RGB interval

Writing something like:

```
Graphics3D[{RGBColor[RandomInteger[{0, 1}], RandomInteger[{0, 1}], RandomInteger[{0, 1}]],
            Sphere[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}, #[[4]]] & /@ SphereList...
```

...appears to only assign one random color to all of the spheres.

I can force this to work by generating a string that explicitly specifies a random color for each sphere, but *is there a simpler way to make this work?*

Comment: Related / relevant (and a classic): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1900/131

Comment: you know your original works just fine, except by using randominteger[0,1] you end up with only 8 colors

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A cute way to do this is by using `Riffle` with an `Unevaluated` second argument:

```
spherelist =  Sphere[{##2}, Abs[0.2 #]] & @@@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 4}];

Graphics3D @ Riffle[spherelist, Unevaluated[Random[] // Hue], {1, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

For random red or green use `RandomChoice`:

```
Graphics3D @ Riffle[spherelist, Unevaluated[RandomChoice[{Red, Green}]], {1, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: how can we fine all the balls in an unit cube?

Answer (score 4):

Not very effective, but useful if you go for postprocessing of existing `Graphics` primitives:

```
spheres = 

  Sphere[#[[1 ;; 3]], #[[4]]/2] & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 4}];

Graphics3D[spheres]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics3D[spheres] /. s_Sphere :> Sequence[RGBColor[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]], s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Repeated evalutation will yield individual coloring.

Comment: how can we fine all the balls in an unit cube?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code (using RandomInteger), you could include the "Color-generation" in the pure function, so that any time you map the function on the sphere-list, a new random sample is drawn:

```
Graphics3D[{RGBColor[RandomInteger[{0, 1}], RandomInteger[{0, 1}], 
 RandomInteger[{0, 1}]], 
 Sphere[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}, #[[4]]]} & /@ 
 RandomReal[5, {10, 4}]]
```

[image]

and likewise:

```
Graphics3D[{RandomChoice[{Red, Green}], 
Sphere[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}, #[[4]]]} & /@ 
RandomReal[5, {10, 4}]]
```

for red/green:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With **V10** we can use `RandomColor`

```
Graphics3D[Table[{RandomColor[],
   Sphere[RandomReal[{.1, .9}, 3], RandomReal[{0.03, 0.08}]]}, {50}],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[Table[{RandomColor[1, ColorSpace -> "LUV"],
   Sphere[RandomReal[{.1, .9}, 3], RandomReal[{0.03, 0.08}]]}, {50}],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a function that returns a list, where the first element is the color and the second element the sphere. Then you apply that function to your list of spheres.

```
coloredSphere[coordinates_] := {RGBColor[Sequence @@ RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 3]], 
    Sphere[coordinates[[;; 3]], coordinates[[4]]]};

Graphics3D[coloredSphere /@ listOfSpheres]
```

[image]

Also, you might want to use `RandomReal` instead of `RandomInteger`, but that's up to you.

Edit: The `Flatten` inside Graphics3D is not even necessary, as I realized by reading the other reply.

Comment: ...always that much better with added `Graphics3D`...