# Graphics3D: How to arrange ViewPoint etc to get Star Wars opening scene battleship overflight?

Tags: graphics3d

I'd like to see if I can get a `Graphics3D` animation of something akin to the opening scene of Star Wars where a battle ship flies in overhead (2:17 into [this clip](https://youtu.be/yHfLyMAHrQE?t=137)).

This has some similarities to this thread: [How can this confetti code be improved to include shadows and gravity?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1900/how-can-this-confetti-code-be-improved-to-include-shadows-and-gravity), especially the later (whimsical) answers.

I've tried playing with this as a way to understand `ViewPoint`, etc:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   Cuboid[{-1, -1, -.01}, {1, 1, .01}],
   Sphere[{0, 0.9, s}, .1]
   }, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 20}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, z}, ViewAngle -> alpha, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, ViewCenter -> {0, 0, 0}
  ],
 {{z, 5}, 0, 25},
 {{s, 0}, 0, 20},
 {alpha, 0, Pi/2}
 ]
```

However, this isn't doing what I expected: when the sphere goes towards the viewpoint, it should get larger.