# Is there a way to make the tick marks larger?

Tags: plotting

In a `Plot` (actually, a `Graphics`) command, I'd like to make the actual tick marks larger than they are, but I can't find an option to do that. Is there a way?

Comment: You've seen the documentation for `Ticks` (`FrameTicks` if you're using frames instead of axes)? Check the tick mark option settings.

Comment: Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Ticks -> {{{Pi, 180 \[Degree], 1}, {2 Pi, 360 \[Degree], 1}, {3 Pi, 
     540 \[Degree], 1}}, {-1, 1}}]

Comment: @J.M. I did see `FrameTicks`, but unfortunately that does not seem to work unless I'm using frames (which I cannot in this application).

Comment: @belisarius That's great, thanks. I hadn't seen that in the documentation. Should work perfectly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others notes, if you manually give the [ticks specification](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html), it's easy to specify sizes for ticks.  But then you need to generate all tick mark positions, including small and big marks, yourself.

Unfortunately, I have never found a way to reliably retrieve the automatically generated ticks specification.  While @J.M.'s answer tries to do this, you'll notice that `AbsoluteOptions` doesn't return *exactly* the same ticks that were generated automatically.

An often recommended alternative is using the [CustomTicks package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) (I learned about it from @Eli and @R.M.).  It is also part of LevelScheme, so I recommend you install [the latest version of LevelScheme](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) instead.  This package will spare you the pain of implementing your own tick-generator functions.

This is how you could use it:

```
<< LevelScheme`CustomTicks`

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> LinTicks]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Increase the tick sizes generated by the `LinTicks` functions:

```
SetOptions[LinTicks, MajorTickLength -> {0.02, 0}, MinorTickLength -> {0.013, 0}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> LinTicks]
```

Documentation for the package is [here](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/CustomTicksGuide.pdf).

Comment: While I just started using a variant of Belisarius' answer above, this looks like a great package. Since in my application I want irregular user-specified ticks, I think this should exactly do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: **Downvoters:** If you don't explain what's wrong with this answer, I won't be able to correct it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, this does not work when I set `Frame->True`. How can I use this package to set the ticks lengths  when using frames?

Comment: @Miguel `Ticks` are for `Axes`, `FrameTicks` are for `Frame`.

Comment: `LevelScheme` has been obsoleted by `SciDraw` which, unfortunately, is now old and causes various name conflicts with *Mathematica* 11.3.

Comment: @murray There is only a single name conflict, but it does not cause any issues (except that the `BoundingRegion` function of SciDraw will not work). The CustomTicks package can be loaded independently from the rest of SciDraw.

Answer (score 18):

From belisarius' comment above:

```
Plot[Cos[x], 
    {x, 0, 10}, 
    Ticks ->{{{Pi, 180°, .1}, {2 Pi, 360°, .1}, {3 Pi, 540°, .1}}, {-1, 1}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note that you can also separately control the length of the two ends of each tick. E.g., in the`Ticks` specification above, replace `.1` by `{.1,.05}` to make the tick stick out twice as far above the x-axis as below the x-axis.

Answer (score 13):

Start with

```
pt = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: sine plot]

Then, to increase the tick size, try the following:

```
c = 3; (* scale factor *)
tx = Map[MapAt[c # &, #, 3] &, Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[pt, Ticks], {2}];
Show[pt, Ticks -> tx]
```

[image: sine plot with bigger ticks]

A similar thing can be done if you're using frames (`Frame -> True`) instead of axes; for that, you use `FrameTicks` instead of `Ticks`. See the docs for more details on those (as well as with `AbsoluteOptions[]`).

Comment: But this increased the number of tick marks and changed how labels are formatted (`6.` instead of `6`).  :-(

Comment: Must be something screwy with `AbsoluteOptions[]`. (It wasn't this way before.) I assumed it would get exactly the tick styles used. I'll need to think slightly more about this.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I can't test at the moment; could you try `Block[{test = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]}, GraphicsRow[{test, Show[test, First[AbsoluteOptions[test, Ticks]]]}]]` and see what comes up?

Comment: Still won't do what it's supposed to.  Yes, you are right that there is something wrong with `AbsoluteOptions`.  In 3D it won't even return a tick-list, and in 3D tick sizing is simply broken!  When you increase the ImageResolution in Rasterize, ticks don't scale linearly (they scale according to some weird functions...)  This prevents me from doing proper [antialiasing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200/12) by upscaling then downscaling.  Note how the ticks become near-invisible in the antialiased version in my link.  It's because of this, not because lines get thin.

Comment: There's also something wrong with `FullGraphics`: it will mess up both ticks and grid lines.  I think the reason is that graphics are rendered by the Front End while FullGraphics is just an approximation of this rendering, done by the kernel.  You can even read the source of FullGraphics, and find many relics from pre v6 times.  What It may be that AbsoluteOptions is broken for the same reason.  Why I don't understand is: why would it be necessary that ticks are generated by the front end, not the kernel.  One guess is that tick spacing should depend on font sizes, which is know only to the FE

Comment: Crap, that was precisely the alternative I was going to pursue... :( it will take me a while to think of how to fix this.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point I think there is no way to fix this.  There doesn't seem to be a completely reliable way to retrieve the automatically generated ticks (`Ticks -> Automatic`).  The usual advice is to use the [CustomTicks package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) (also part of LevelScheme) to automate generating reasonable ticks, then it's easy to transform the tick specification later.

Comment: In that case, I'll add a caveat to this answer later...

Comment: I wrote another answer where I recommend custom ticks.  As something related: I'd really like to have a meta question where people can post any package they use (packages they actually use in practice!!) as answers, and others who also use them could upvote those posts.  It would be good for sharing one's own packages as well.  Because of the voting and because of the requirement to vote for packages you *use* (not ones you found), this would be a completely different resource from MathSource and IMO quite useful.  Thoughts? (In chat.)