# Specifying unlabeled FrameTicks in Plot

Tags: plotting

I am running *Mathematica* 7.  Suppose that I plot $\sin(x)$ for $x = 0..10$ and frame the plot using `Frame -> True`:

> ```
> Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
> ```
>
> [image: Plot 1]

Now suppose that I would like the horizontal axis to have ticks every $0.5$ (which it does), but with the ticks *labeled* only every $1$.  Is there a way to do this?

`FrameTicks` seemed to be a possibility, but when I used `Range[0, 10, 1]` in the bottom horizontal axis specification, I lost the (non-labeled) ticks at every $0.5$:

> ```
> Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
>  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[0, 10, 1], Automatic}}]
> ```
>
> [image: Plot 2]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The [CustomTicks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) package is the way to go, IMHO.

Comment: Does `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Join[Range[0, 10], Thread[{Range[0.5, 10, 1.], " "}]], Automatic}}]` work?

Comment: With the documentation for Frameticks or the results of this search http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=frameticks you should have no trouble.

Comment: @kguler Yes, that indeed does work.  Thank you!

Comment: [Here's an example of using `CustomTicks`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6054/12).  I think you'd end up rewriting the same thing anyway.  It saves times to just use CustomTicks and you'll get a prettier output with less work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using kguler's comment (thank you!), I get the following, which is the output I was looking for:

> ```
> Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
>  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
>   {Join[Range[0, 10], Thread[{Range[0.5, 10, 1], " "}]], Automatic}}]
> ```
>
> [image: Plot 3]

Comment: you can control the labels,positions and styling of ticks more finely using the second, third and fourth arguments. Try, for example, `Frameticks-> {{Automatic, 
   Automatic}, {Join[{#, #, {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[0, 10], {#, " ", {.0075, 0}, Directive[Red, Thick]} & /@ Range[0.5, 10, 1.]], Automatic}}`. (+1)