# Custom (Frame)Ticks fail when using Mathematica's script engine

Tags: plotting, scripting, ticks

I want to define my own ticks in a `DateListPlot`. It works quite well when I use the code in a *Mathematica* Notebook but breaks somehow when using it via *Mathematica*'s script engine.

First of all the code:

```
Clear[fticks,plot];
fticks[min_, max_] := 
  Module[{nTicks = 9}, Table[{min + i (max - min)/nTicks,
     DateString[
      DateList[min + i (max - min)/nTicks], {"Month", ".", "Year"}]
     }, {i, 1, nTicks - 1}]];
plot = DateListPlot[
  FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"],
  FrameTicks -> {fticks, Automatic, None, None}
  ]
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "test-plot.png"}], plot];
```

In my `fticks` function I generate some ticks depending on the `min`and `max`values of the `DateListPlot`. This can't be completely wrong since the result works quite well.

[image: Ticks are working when computed in a Mathematica Notebook file]

But as soon as I try to calculate it via the *Mathematica* script engine, the custom ticks fail. (I've saved the code above in a file located at `~/test.m` as *Mathematica* uses `*.m` files for its scripting engine).

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -script ~/test.m
```

The result comes without any ticks but a red overlay because of an error. The question is now why is it not working? Interesting is also that while editing the `test.m` file there is also the possibility to run the package. I don't know why but this also works.

[image: Ticks are not working when computed via the Mathematica script engine]

I work in *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0 running on Mac OS X 10.8. This error also occurs in *Mathematica* 8 as I've tested.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you're missing a `;` after the `plot = ...` command.

Comment: Mhm, I tried it with a `;` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-tick-marks-larger). A comment from szabolcs suggest that the front end is needed to render custom ticks...

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution. I played around writing the `FrameTicks` function as a pure function. The problem seems to be that the argument passed to the `fticks` function are `DateList` generated lists and not of type `Real` when using the script engine. Don't ask me why but they are of type `Real` when using the graphical frontend (does somebody know why?). This difference seems to cause the error when using the script engine instead of the graphical interface.

To calculate the corresponding `Real` value I used `AbsoluteTiming` in my solution `fticks2`.

It is interesting that the ticks are still not displayed when writing the function not as a pure function (see my attempt `fticks3`). I'm not sure why this happens. If you can comment on that please let me know.

Here is the solution for the interested people:

```
Clear[fticks,fticks2,fticks3,plot];

(* not working *)
fticks[min_,max_]:=Module[{nTicks=9},Table[{min+i (max-min)/nTicks,
DateString[DateList[min+i (max-min)/nTicks],{"Month",".","Year"}]
},{i,1,nTicks-1}]];

(* working *)
fticks2=Module[{nTicks=9,min=AbsoluteTime@#1,max=AbsoluteTime@#2},Table[{min+i (max-min)/nTicks,
DateString[DateList[min+i (max-min)/nTicks],{"Month",".","Year"}]
},{i,1,nTicks-1}]]&;

(* not working *)
fticks3[minList_,maxList_]:=Module[{nTicks=9,min=AbsoluteTime@minList,max=AbsoluteTime@maxList},Table[{min+i (max-min)/nTicks,
DateString[DateList[min+i (max-min)/nTicks],{"Month",".","Year"}]
},{i,1,nTicks-1}]];

plot=DateListPlot[
FinancialData["IBM","Jan. 1, 2004"],
FrameTicks->{fticks2,Automatic,None,None}
];
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory,"test.png"}],plot];
```

This generates the following output and therefore is perfect for my needs.

[image: Output using pure function]

So there are still some open questions but also a working solution. Nevertheless thanks to anyone who thought about the problem.