# How to make the Ticks larger?

Tags: visualization, options, ticks, number-representation

I can´t find the option for larger ticks

```
NumberLinePlot[{0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize[0.00016]], 
 AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.004], TicksStyle -> {Thickness[0.004]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {20, Bold}, ImageSize -> Full, 
 Ticks -> Table[i, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]]
```

Answer (score 7):

[`Ticks -> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)

[image]

```
NumberLinePlot[{0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize[0.00016]], 
 AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.004], TicksStyle -> {Thickness[0.004]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {20, Bold}, ImageSize -> Full, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, .02}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], None}]
```

[image]

Use `Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, {.02, 0}}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], None}` to get

[image]

Use `Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, {0, .02}}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], None}` to get

[image]

To get tick positions automatically selected, use the function `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` with the option `TicksLength` (or `"TicksLength"`):

```
Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
      TicksLength -> {.02, 0}][##] /. _AbsoluteThickness -> 
     Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]] &, None}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

xticks = Join[{#, 
      "", {0.01`, 0.`}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.6`]}} & /@
     Range[0, 2, 0.1],
   {#, #, {0.02`, 0.`}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[1]}} & /@ 
    Range[0, 2, 0.5]];

nlp = NumberLinePlot[{0, 2},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize[0.00016]],
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.004],
  LabelStyle -> {20, Bold},
  ImageSize -> Full,
  Ticks -> {xticks, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-tick-marks-larger). [LevelScheme](https://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) does that.