# 3d graphic for publication

Tags: graphics

Journals are very strict and some of them require special formats. They suggest the .tiff or .jpg format for graphics with many colors. I have problem how to export, for example, this figure consists of 4 smaller but to have optimized quality (Labels to be with correct size of fonts, viewable) and not with large file size.

```
plot1 = Plot3D[Sin[4 x]*Cos[4 y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotLabel -> "number 1, gamma, s=1,q=2", AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
ColorFunction -> "NeonColors"];

plot2 = Plot3D[Sin[3 x]*Cos[4 y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotLabel -> "number 1, gamma, s=2,q=2", AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
ColorFunction -> "NeonColors"];

plot3 = Plot3D[Sin[2 x]*Cos[4 y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotLabel -> "number 1, gamma, s=3,q=2", AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
ColorFunction -> "NeonColors"];

plot4 = Plot3D[Sin[1 x]*Cos[4 y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotLabel -> "number 1, gamma, s=4,q=2", AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
ColorFunction -> "NeonColors"];

GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot2}, {plot3, plot4}}, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Have you looked up `Export`, `JPG` and `TIFF` in the documentation center?  What didn't work about the examples there?  There's also File > Save Selection As in the menu.

Comment: quality of labels and optimized file size because I have 4 figures into one

Comment: `finalplot=GraphicsGrid[...]` and `Export["path/image.jpg",finalplot]`? I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/HuQ35t4.png).

Comment: yes, but this quality is not good

Comment: and I need to change font to be very good quality, this is not ready for publication for example

Comment: @Öskå The quality in the image is not good because you haven't turned on anti-aliasing. Go Preferences -> Appearance and turn it to max before you export it.

Comment: Have you tried something like `ImageResolution -> 600`?

Comment: Well, there are many questions here about `Export` and `Style` :) I usually don't use the basic `Export` when I do it "for me", the question is quite foggy since there is no real question apart from the comments :)

Comment: With Image resolution is better, but maybe it is better to change font size and something else to looks like nicer

Comment: @Öskå Yes, I agree the posted question could be edited to be more specific about what is desired.  But this question might end up OT/in-the-manual and put on hold.

Comment: @Pipe, font can be added like `PlotLabel -> Style["YourText", "YourFont"]`. But like Michael said, it's in the documentation, and the `Export` has been treated lots of time on here.

Comment: @Pipe You can change `FontFamily`, but the number of pixels in the image is connected to the grainy quality of the rendered font.  `ImageResolution` is one way to control the resolution of the image. :)

Comment: I think you need to specify what is your resolution target. Size and dpi or number of pixels. Then you could use `Rasterize` and specify `RasterSize`.

Comment: and finally, @Pickett [this](http://i.imgur.com/5Y01tg7.png) is better indeed, tack så mycket ;o)

Comment: ... and perhaps related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198/131. My favorite for images with uniform background is PNG.

Comment: @YvesKlett But PNG is far future for publishers. They are happy that they know tiff

Comment: For this example, tiff and png look quite good and basically identical if given adequate resolution, eg. `"ImageSize" -> 3000`