# Anti-aliasing a fractal-like bitmap image

Tags: image-processing

I have a .bmp image 9600x5400 that shows a lot of points at various intensities. There are no lines inside this picture - only a lot of points.
I would like to apply anti-aliasing on the image to make it smoother (and more beautiful).

Can Mathematica help me on that?

[image]

Comment: For such a large image, you might want to try "out-of-core" functions such as [`ImageFileFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageFileFilter.html).

Comment: Thank you @Silvia. Could you post an answer on this?

Comment: I would love to, but I'm not sure how to realize an anti-aliasing effect..

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200/17) is a poorman's anti-aliasing. For your dots image, I might also want to try [`CurvatureFlowFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurvatureFlowFilter.html).

Comment: That looks like a map of Greece. Is it?

Comment: Could you post a link to the original (9600x5400) picture?

Comment: Yes @DeusDeceit it is a map of Greece + Turkey + Balkans! The rest to 9600x5400 is the whole world.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You know noisy financial stocks behaviour can be modeled with fractals? Meaning one is the other ;-) So how do you filter one from the other?..

Wavelets can sometimes pick up just the right sort of noise to smooth so it leaves meaningful information mostly untouched.

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzHKm.jpg"];
```

- Perform DiscreteWaveletTransform - ***play*** with choice of wavelet - we pick CDFWavelet
- Threshold wavelet coefficients - ***play*** how - we do "SmoothGarrote"
- Synthesize smoothed image using InverseWaveletTransform and compare with original:

Here it is:

```
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[i, CDFWavelet[]];
thr = WaveletThreshold[dwd, "SmoothGarrote"]
{Image[InverseWaveletTransform[thr], ImageSize -> All], Image[i, ImageSize -> All]}
```

[image]

In this specific case we got lucky and got an impressive result I think. Note - execute on your machine - images you see are a screenshot - it's like listening music through the wall, - but in this case pretty thin wall I guess.

If result would be not that good play with the bold ***play*** parts ;-)

Don't ask how it works "exactly" - we both would need read up on wavelets ;-)

Example is taken from [**Documentation**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0czgd91pbxobj4mdftt-bd3uf9).

Comment: Thank you for your answer this seems very interesting. I will try to apply it in my Huge picture using also Silvia's hint on `ImageFileFilter`.

Comment: @tchronis if the meaningful feature scales are much less than image size then you can also just cut the image - ImagePartition, filter pieces via say ParallelMap, and then ImageAssemble.