# Plotting the Star of Bethlehem

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics, performance-tuning, visualization

Christmas is around the corner! In preparation, consider the polynomial

```
f[x_,y_]:= 1/10 (4 - x^2 - 2 y^2)^2 + 1/2 (x^2 + y^2)
```

and define $r=(f_x,f_y)$ using the first-order partial derivatives such that

```
r[x_,y_]:={x (-3 + 2 x^2 + 4 y^2)/5, y (-11 + 4 x^2 + 8 y^2)/5}
```

and $F=f_{xx}\cdot f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2$ using the second-order partial derivatives such that

```
F[x_,y_]:= (33 + 24 x^4 - 116 y^2 + 96 y^4 - 78 x^2 + 96 x^2 y^2)/25
```

The question is how to plot the following 'implicit' function efficiently and sharp in Mathematica?

$$Z(s,t)= \sum_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\, r(x,y)=(s,t)} \frac{1}{\left|  F(x,y) \right|}$$

It should look like this in $[-1,1]^2$: (when black indicates zero and white large values)

[image]

Actually, the fastes contributions are from

- @xzczd (backward way, tracing $r^{-1}$)
- @George Varnavides (forward way, tracing $r$)

Most elegant solution from

- @Roman

**Addendum:**
If you successfully plotted the star you may try the following function as input

```
f=ListInterpolation[RandomReal[2,{9,9}]+Outer[#1^2+#2^2&, Range[9], Range[9]]/2];
```

leading to $Z$ looking like this:
[image]

Comment: Interesting community question! Also looking forward to the contributions from the experts like @Bob Hanlon.

Comment: or  @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: or @Michael E2 .

Comment: I believe I can plot it efficiently (in the sense of computation time. But it does not look particularly artistic. (When it comes to graphics, I'm no star, Bethelhem or otherwise. More like dark matter I'm afraid.)

Comment: Wasn't the star of Bethlehem 3D?  Where are all the cowboys?

Comment: "[Citation needed]" -- Meaning why do you (and the rest) think that that star looks that way?

Comment: I do post here on behalf of Santa Clause and he claimed that.

Comment: Umm, @fwgb, what about [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZQROJsdYF0)?

Comment: What's the range of $(s,t)$ for the `f` in **Addendum**? Still $[-1,1]^2$?

Comment: @xzczd I would suggest the interval $[1,9]^2$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hint: $Z$ is the Jacobian for the transformation between $(x,y)$ and $(s,t)$ coordinates. No need to even define $Z$, no need to invert polynomials, no branch cuts.

```
f[x_, y_] = 1/10 (4 - x^2 - 2 y^2)^2 + 1/2 (x^2 + y^2);
r[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}];

With[{span = 2, step = 0.001, binsize = 1/100},
  DensityHistogram[
    Join @@ Table[r[x, y], {x, -span, span, step}, {y, -span, span, step}],
    {-1, 1, binsize},
    ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]]
```

[image]

Same idea but much faster (takes 1.9 seconds on my laptop):

```
With[{span = 1.72, step = 0.001, binsize = 1/100},
  ArrayPlot[
    Transpose@BinCounts[Transpose[
      r @@ Transpose[Tuples[Range[-span, span, step], 2]]], {-1,1,binsize}, {-1,1,binsize}],
    ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]]
```

where the number 1.72 is `Root[-5-3#+2#^3&, 1]`, as gleaned from `Reduce[Thread[-1 <= r[x,y] <= 1], {x,y}]`.

### Addendum

This method works with the addendum question as well:

```
f = ListInterpolation[
      RandomReal[2, {9, 9}] + Outer[#1^2 + #2^2 &, Range[9], Range[9]]/2];
r[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}];

With[{step = 0.005, binsize = 1/10},
  ArrayPlot[Transpose@BinCounts[Transpose[
    r @@ Transpose[Tuples[Range[1, 9, step], 2]]],
    {0, 10, binsize}, {0, 10, binsize}],
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]]
```

[image]

I'll leave it to skillful experts to make prettier plots. Here I'm only addressing the question of plotting efficiency.

Comment: Your're right, $Z$ is the factor when using the substitution formula for two variables.

Comment: Very elegant code. The only downer is it takes a lot of time to get a sharp plot.

Comment: @fwgb the method is extremely efficient; the implementation is slow. For more speed, try `With[{span = 2, step = 0.01, binsize = 1/100}, ArrayPlot[Transpose@BinCounts[Join @@ Table[r[x, y], {x, -span, span, step}, {y, -span, span, step}], {-1, 1, binsize}, {-1, 1, binsize}], ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]]` or do everything directly in C. There's nothing fancy going on here, so a translation to a low-level language is trivial.

Comment: I agree, I call this the 'forward' way, as we trace $r$ forward. Although, the 'backward' way as used in @xzczd answer (2nd part) looks much sharper in the same amount of comp. time.

Comment: Good job, its faster now. For some reason I get the 'memory exceeded' message, although it doesn't use that much memory.

Comment: Using `binsize=1/250` and `Image[0.005* ...]` instead of `ArrayPlot` looks even better. I cannot get lower than `stepsize=0.0011` with memory.

Comment: A very clever idea. Its very fast, but I also have the memory issue.

Comment: @darksun if memory is an issue, just make `step` a bit larger and you'll be fine. I chose it extra small.

Comment: Using `Sum[Transpose@BinCounts[Transpose[r@@Transpose[Tuples[Range[-span+step*i/n, span+step*j/n, step], 2]]], {-1,1,binsize}, {-1,1,binsize}],{i,0,n-1},{j,0,n-1}];` inside the plot can drastically reduce the memory or increase the sharpness by a factor of $n^2$.

Comment: Er… by "No need to even define $Z$" do you mean $Z$ is not needed to generate a star-like picture, or the plot will still be the visualization of $Z$ even if $Z$ isn't explicitly defined?

Comment: @fwgb The faster version of my program uses less than 900 MB of memory (as given by [`MaxMemoryUsed[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxMemoryUsed.html) so I believe your memory problems may be elsewhere. Did you run this on a fresh kernel?

Comment: @xzczd I mean the latter: we can plot a visualization of $Z$ even if $Z$ isn't explicitly defined. Because $Z$ is a Jacobian, we start with a uniform density in $(x,y)$ space and implicitly find the density in $(s,t)$ space as a histogram, proportional to $Z$.

Comment: Wery Clewer, that.

Comment: This is my favorite solution out of the whole lot.

Answer (score 20):

The *noise* in the picture given by OP seems to suggest random number has been used, so here's my trial:

```
data = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {2, 4 10^5}];

s = 1000;
func = Function[{x, y}, Round@Rescale[r[x, y], {-1, 1}, {1, s}] -> 1/Abs@F[x, y], 
   Listable];

stFlst = func @@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.87326, Null} *)

SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];

array = SparseArray[
    DeleteCases[stFlst, ({x_, y_} -> _) /; ! (1 < x < s && 1 < y < s)], {s, 
     s}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.655598, Null} *)

ArrayPlot[array // Transpose, PlotRange -> {0, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image]

---

The following is a fast smooth plot, based on the discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73312/1871):

```
Clear[s, x, y]

sol = {x, y} /. Solve[r[x, y] == {s, t}, {x, y}];

symbolicroots = Cases[sol, a__Root, Infinity] // Union

coef = CoefficientList[symbolicroots[[1, 1, 1]], #]

{x, y} = sol[[1]] /. __Root -> ro

nroots[c_List] := Block[{a}, a = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1., Length@c - 2], 1];
   a[[-1]] = -Most@c/Last@c;
   Eigenvalues[a]];

check = Function @@ {If[Abs@Im@# < 10^-6, 1, 0] // PiecewiseExpand // 
    Simplify`PWToUnitStep}

eps = 10^-6; dt = 2 10^-3; 
 data = ParallelTable[
   Block[{ro = Pick[#, check@#, 1] &@nroots[coef]}, 
    1/F[x, y] // Abs // Total], {s, -1 + eps, 1 + eps, dt}, {t, -1 + eps, 1 + eps, 
    dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {34.7344, Null}, dual core laptop *)    

ArrayPlot[data // Transpose, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", PlotRange -> {0, 30}]
```

[image]

---

## Solution to Addendum

The method above for smooth plot no longer works well on the `f` in addendum, but the first method using random number still works. I've used [`InterpolationToPiecewise`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753/1871) to transform the `InterpolatingFunction` to something compilable.

```
SeedRandom["star"]; 
dataf = RandomReal[2, {9, 9}] + Outer[#1^2 + #2^2 &, Range[9], Range[9]]/2;

InterpolationToPiecewise[if_, x_] := Module[{main, default, grid}, grid = if["Grid"];
   Piecewise[{if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #], x < First@#} & /@ grid[[2 ;; -2]], 
   if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #] &@grid[[-1]]]] /; if["InterpolationMethod"] == "Hermite"

poly[x_, y_] = 
  InterpolationToPiecewise[
   ListInterpolation[InterpolationToPiecewise[ListInterpolation[#], y] & /@ dataf], x];

compile = Compile[{x, y}, #, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] &;
r = compile@D[poly[x, y], {{x, y}}];
absdivideF = 
  Abs@Divide[1, (D[#, x, x] D[#, y, y] - D[#, x, y]^2)] &@poly[x, y] // compile;

domain = {0, 10};
{datax, datay} = RandomReal[domain, {2, 10^6}];

s = 1000;
func = Function[{x, y}, 
  Clip[Round@Rescale[r[x, y], domain, {1, s}], {1, s}] -> absdivideF[x, y]];

stFlst = func[datax, datay]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.93232, Null} *)

SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
array = SparseArray[stFlst, {s, s}];
ArrayPlot[array // Transpose, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image]

### Remark

If you have a C compiler installed, consider using the following definition of `compile`:

```
compile = Last@
    Compile[{{xlst, _Real, 1}, {ylst, _Real, 1}}, 
     Block[{x, y}, Table[x = xlst[[i]]; y = ylst[[i]]; #, {i, Length@xlst}]], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] &;
```

It will vastly speed up the generation of `stFlst`, at the expense of long compilation time of `r` and `absdivideF`.

Comment: My picture was indeed done that way, but not so elegant. The problem, it takes a lot of points to get sharp results.

Comment: Very nice, you added even the check for complex roots. I'm still about to figure out how the general approach works, give me a bit.

Comment: The sharpest plot so far. Is `root` not the same as `roots[coef]`? And what does/is `xy`?

Comment: @fwgb `root` and `roots[coef]` are the same, but `roots` is faster as a numeric solver, see the linked post for more info. `xy` is $(x, y)$ expressed using `s`, `t` and `ro`, where `ro` denotes `Root[-20 s^3 + 8 s^2 #1 + 7 s #1^2 + (-3 + 8 s^2 + 4 t^2) #1^3 - 8 s #1^4 + 
   2 #1^5 &,(*1,2,…,5*)]`

Comment: @fwgb I've adjusted the variable names to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 18):

A compiled version of @Roman's idea (binning code adapted from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50843/41179)):

```
starCompiled = 
 Compile[{{xyspan, _Real}, {delta, _Real}, {binspan, _Real}, \
{binsize, _Real}}, 
  Block[{bins, dimx, dimy, x, y, tx, ty}, 
   bins = Table[
     0, {Floor[binspan 2/binsize] + 1}, {Floor[binspan 2/binsize] + 
       1}];
   {dimx, dimy} = Dimensions[bins];
   Do[{x, y} = {xx - 2/5 xx (4 - xx^2 - 2 yy^2), 
      yy - 4/5 yy (4 - xx^2 - 2 yy^2)};
    tx = Floor[(x + binspan)/binsize] + 1;
    ty = Floor[(y + binspan)/binsize] + 1;
    If[tx >= 1 && tx <= dimx && ty >= 1 && ty <= dimy, 
     bins[[tx, ty]] += 1], {xx, -xyspan, xyspan, delta}, {yy, -xyspan,
      xyspan, delta}];
   bins], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

I seem to get a ~3.5x speedup on my machine, with this relatively sharp image taking ~1.5 seconds:

```
ArrayPlot[starCompiled[1.72,0.0005,1.,0.005]^\[Transpose],Frame->False,ColorFunction->"AvocadoColors"]
```

[image]

## Addendum

For completeness, here's a compiled version of the binning along idea on the addendum.
Credit for the compiled interpolating function goes to @xzczd and reference therein.

```
dataf = RandomReal[2, {9, 9}] + 
   Outer[#1^2 + #2^2 &, Range[9], Range[9]]/2;
InterpolationToPiecewise[if_, x_] := 
 Module[{main, default, grid}, grid = if["Grid"];
   Piecewise[{if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #], x < First@#} & /@ 
     grid[[2 ;; -2]], if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #] &@grid[[-1]]]] /; 
  if["InterpolationMethod"] == "Hermite"
poly[x_, y_] = 
  InterpolationToPiecewise[
   ListInterpolation[
    InterpolationToPiecewise[ListInterpolation[#], y] & /@ dataf], 
   x];
compile = 
  Compile[{x, y}, #, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] &;
r = compile@D[poly[x, y], {{x, y}}];
addendumCompiled = 
 Compile[{{xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {ymin, _Real}, {ymax, _Real}, \
{delta, _Real}, {binsize, _Real}}, 
  Block[{bins, dimx, dimy, x, y, tx, ty}, 
   bins = Table[
     0, {Floor[(xmax - xmin)/binsize] + 
       1}, {Floor[(ymax - ymin)/binsize] + 1}];
   {dimx, dimy} = Dimensions[bins];
   Do[{x, y} = r[xx, yy];
    tx = Floor[(x - xmin)/binsize] + 1;
    ty = Floor[(y - ymin)/binsize] + 1;
    If[tx >= 1 && tx <= dimx && ty >= 1 && ty <= dimy, 
     bins[[tx, ty]] += 1], {xx, xmin, xmax, delta}, {yy, ymin, ymax, 
     delta}];
   bins], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

Seems to be relatively fast (and `CompilePrint` confirms no calls to `MainEvaluator`):

```
AbsoluteTiming[bins = addendumCompiled[1, 9, 1, 9, 0.0005, 0.005];]
Image@Rescale@Log[bins + 1]
```

[image]

## PS

Potentially (un)related (any politics aside), here's the same idea on a complex strange attractor given by the equation (from the book `Symmetry in Chaos: A Search for Pattern in Mathematics, Art and Nature`):
$$
F(z) = \left(\lambda + \alpha z z^* + \beta \Re(z^n) + \delta \Re\left[\left(\frac{z}{|z|}\right)^{np}\right]|z|\right)z + \gamma z^{*n-1}
$$

```
attractorNonLinear = 
 Compile[{{xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {ymin, _Real}, {ymax, _Real}, \
{delta, _Real}, {itmax, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {lambda, _Real}, \
{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {c, _Real}, {d, _Real}, {p, _Integer}}, 
  Block[{bins, dim, x, y, tx, ty, z, b1, radii, normed, coordinates},
   bins = 
    Table[0, {Floor[(xmax - xmin)/delta] + 
       1}, {Floor[(ymax - ymin)/delta] + 1}];
   dim = Dimensions[bins];
   z = -0.3 + 0.2 I;
   Do[z = (lambda + a z Conjugate[z] + b Re[z^n] + 
         d Re[(z/Abs[z])^n p] Abs[z]) z + c Conjugate[z]^(n - 1);
    {x, y} = {Re[z], Im[z]};
    tx = Floor[(x - xmin)/delta] + 1;
    ty = Floor[(y - ymin)/delta] + 1;
    If[tx >= 1 && tx <= dim[[1]] && ty >= 1 && ty <= dim[[2]], 
     bins[[tx, ty]] += 1], {i, 1, itmax}];
   bins], CompilationTarget :> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

which gives the Star of David with the following parameter values:

```
AbsoluteTiming[bins=N[attractorNonLinear[-1.6,1.6,-1.6,1.6,0.001,5 10^7,6,-2.42,1.0,-0.04,0.14,0.088,0]];]
ArrayPlot[Log[bins+1],ColorFunction->"AvocadoColors",Frame->False]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, compile is always worth a try! Is it even possible to include my idea to reduce the memory consumption to almost zero I commented under Roman's answer?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve by the suggestion? How small of a delta/binsize are you using? `MaxMemoryUsed[starCompiled[1.72,0.0001,1.,0.001]]10^-6.` which produces a 2001x2001 array seems to use less than 100MB

Comment: Ah, sorry. Since you're not using `BinCounts` you don't have that problem. You create the `{x,y}` one by one and not all at the same time which needs a lot of memory.

Comment: Seems to be the fastest code so far also for the addendum. I would prob. use `Image` with scaled bins for plotting.

Comment: sure - thanks for the suggestion, edited

Answer (score 16):

Some code, built for speed, building on @Roman's idea of projecting `r[x, y]`:

```
rr[x_, y_] := {x (-3 + 2 x^2 + 4 y^2)/5, y (-11 + 4 x^2 + 8 y^2)/5};
FF[x_, y_] := (33 + 24 x^4 - 116 y^2 + 96 y^4 - 78 x^2 + 96 x^2 y^2)/
   25;

PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock@Infinity};
Block[{n, x, y, r, F, classes, clusters},
   {r, F} = {rr[x, y], FF[x, y]} /. {Power[v_, n_] :> v[n], 
      v : x | y :> v[1]};
   n = 1000;
   (* x,y coordinates *)
   {x[1], y[1]} = Transpose@Tuples[Subdivide[-1.8, 1.8, n], 2];
   (* x,y dithering *)
   {x[1], y[1]} += RandomReal[2/n {-1, 1}, Dimensions@{x[1], y[1]}];
   (* powers of x,y for r,F *)
   {x[2], y[2]} = {x[1], y[1]}^2;
   {x[4], y[4]} = {x[2], y[2]}^2;
   (* opacity, point size depend on class = magnitude(F) *)
   classes = Round[Abs[F], 5];
   clusters = GatherBy[Range[(n + 1)^2], classes[[#]] &];
   star = Graphics[{White,
      GraphicsComplex[
       r // Transpose,
       With[{class = classes[[First@#]]},
          With[{s = (4. + 4. class^1.5)/n},
           {PointSize[s], Opacity[0.0004/n/s^2], Point@#}
           ]] & /@ clusters]
      },
     Background -> Black, PlotRange -> 1.1]
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.225483, Null}  *)
```

There's a Moiré effect if you leave out the dithering (second `{x[1], y[1]}` line), which may be seen as pretty by some.  It can be changed somewhat by manipulating the size parameter `s`.  The size and opacity do not quite scale with `n`, and I gave trying to make it work exactly.  Calculating `n = 2000` took only 1 sec. Rendering `n = 2000` led to a crash. I tried it twice, because my laptop often crashes for other reasons; but two crashes suggest `n = 2000` exceeds the limits of my machine.  Here is `n = 1000`:

```
img = Image@star; // AbsoluteTiming
img

(*  {2.4411, Null}  *)

star (* renders nicer than img, but takes a little longer *)
```

[image]

---

Interpolating functions are slower, but the operate the same way as other functions:

```
ff = BlockRandom[
   ListInterpolation[
     RandomReal[2, {9, 9}] + 
      Outer[#1^2 + #2^2 &, Range[9], Range[9]]/2][x, y],
   RandomSeeding -> 0];
rr[x_, y_] = D[ff, {{x, y}}];
FF[x_, y_] = Det@D[ff, {{x, y}, 2}];

PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock@Infinity};
Block[{n, x, y, r, F, classes, clusters, pr},
   {r, F} = {rr[x, y], FF[x, y]};
   n = 600;
   {x, y} = Transpose@Tuples[Subdivide[1., 9., n], 2];
   {x, y} += RandomReal[2/n {-1, 1}, Dimensions@{x[1], y[1]}];
   {x, y} = Clip[{x, y}, {1., 9.}];
   
   classes = Round[Abs[F], 5];
   clusters = GatherBy[Range[(n + 1)^2], classes[[#]] &];
   r = r;
   pr = MinMax /@ r;
   star = Graphics[{White,
      GraphicsComplex[
       r // Transpose,
       With[{class = classes[[First@#]]},
          With[{s = (2. + 2. class^1.8)/n},
           {PointSize[s], Opacity[0.0003/n/s^2], Point@#}
           ]] & /@ clusters]
      },
     Background -> Black, PlotRange -> pr]
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {14.0745, Null}  *)

PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock@Infinity};
(img0 = Image[star];
  img = ImageApply[#^{3, 2, 1/3} &, img0];) // AbsoluteTiming
img

(*  {20.255, Null}  *)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks very good already!

Comment: Here's a 3D variant of the last image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ws33.png

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: @fwgb the 3D? Plot `{s, t, Sqrt[x^2+y^2]}` -- almost the same code, just change the first argument of `GraphicsComplex` to `Append[r, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] // Transpose`, change to `Graphics3D`, the point size and opacity, and `PlotRange -> All`. -- Oh, and `n = 200`.  1000 was way too big.

Answer (score 15):

I'll show a picture for now, and add code after others have had time to play around with this.

--- edit ---

[Adding code as promised]

First the input polynomials.

```
poly[x_, y_] := (33 + 24 x^4 - 116 y^2 + 96 y^4 - 78 x^2 + 
    96 x^2 y^2)/25
r[x_, y_] := {x (-3 + 2 x^2 + 4 y^2)/5, y (-11 + 4 x^2 + 8 y^2)/5}
```

Now create a function `z` that is the reciprocal of `poly`, but expressed in terms of `{s,t}` coordinates. We get this via a `GroebnerBasis` computation that eliminates `{x,y}` and gives the reciprocal. (Remark: This method will not work on the addendum problem.) An advantage here is that we get a function directly in terms of the new coordinates and thus do not need to consider the solutions in terms of `{x,y}`.

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[
   Flatten[{{s, t} - r[x, y], z*poly[x, y] - 1}], {z, s, t}, {x, y}];
```

Construct a function that sums the absolute value over the roots of our reciprocal.

```
new[s_, t_] = RootSum[(Evaluate[gb[[1]]] /. z -> #) &, Abs[#] &];
```

And a similar one that only sums the real roots.

```
newReal[s_, t_] = 
  RootSum[(Evaluate[gb[[1]]] /. z -> #) &,
  (1 - Abs[Sign[Im[#]]])*Abs[#] &];
```

--- end edit ---

```
ContourPlot[new[s, t], {s, -1.2, 1.2}, {t, -1.6, 1.6}, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Contours -> {Automatic, 120}]
```

[image]

One alternative is to use a list plot.

```
n = 100000;
randata = With [{pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]},
   Join[pts, Transpose[{Apply[new, pts, 1]}], 2]];

ListDensityPlot[randata, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

No particular improvement in artistry, I'm afraid.
[image]

I add a version that enforces that the roots in question be real-valued. Plot settings dutifully cribbed from response by @BobHanlon.

```
DensityPlot[newReal[s, t], {s, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 75, 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]

Here is an alternative rendition as proposed by @MichaelE2.

```
DensityPlot[newReal[s, t], {s, -1., 1.}, {t, -1., 1.}, 
 PlotPoints -> 75, MaxRecursion -> 4, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[ArcTan[0.25 #]/(Pi/2)] &), 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Here is one these contours.

```
ContourPlot[newReal[s, t] == 3, {s, -1., 1.}, {t, -1., 1.}, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

And here is one rotation, to get the 3D requested by @dominic (I realize the quality is poor).

```
star3D[s_, t_, u_] := newReal[s, t^2 + u^2]
```

[image]

Another rotation looks somewhat like Saturn. In deference to the upcoming solstice planetary event I will not show it; just pretend it is being blocked by Jupiter.

After clarification that requests a surface plot, here is one variant. I sum over all (real and complex) roots in this variant, and also take a square root so as to fit most of the plot in the default range by lowering the peaks. I like the effect from the avocado color scheme others have used,

```
Plot3D[new[s, t]^(1/2), {s, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 150, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

Note that it is somewhat "cuspy". Also there are some spiky parts that get clipped. To see them (and lose much of the rest) one can use `PlotRange->All`. If one uses only real roots the plot is not so nice. I suspect this is due to discontinuities wherein complex-valued roots merge into real values on some curve in the s-t plane (technically, it's a part of the discriminant variety).

[image]

Comment: You might try `ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[ArcTan[0.15 #]/(Pi/2)] &), PlotRange -> All` to diminish the white-out at the top and bottom.  The scaling factor `0.15` might need adjustment. You might get something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jm8b.png

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. That does make for a better picture.

Comment: @Daniel.  Not really what I was suggesting above.  Rather the function Z(s,t) is of course a function of two variables.  What does this surface look like over the s-t plane and even more interesting, what it looks like when s and t are complex and how can it be nicely rendered in color?  I'll try to work on this later.

Comment: Now that looks different!

Comment: Clever idea to use `GroebnerBasis` and `RootSum` this way. What's the runtime?

Comment: `In[779]:= 
Timing[gb = 
    GroebnerBasis[
     Flatten[{{s, t} - r[x, y], z*poly[x, y] - 1}], {z, s, t}, {x, 
      y}];][[1]]

Out[779]= 0.2659` or, faster still, `In[780]:= 
Timing[gb = 
    GroebnerBasis[
     Flatten[{{s, t} - r[x, y], z*poly[x, y] - 1}], {z, s, t}, {x, y},
      MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder];][[1]]

Out[780]= 0.068583` The `RootSum` is the slow part because it needs to be evaluated many times in the plots. The quality density plot takes around 12.3 seconds to evaluate for example.

Answer (score 11):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] := 1/10 (4 - x^2 - 2 y^2)^2 + 1/2 (x^2 + y^2)

r[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] // Simplify;

F[x_, y_] = 
  D[f[x, y], x, x]*D[f[x, y], y, y] - D[f[x, y], x, y]^2 // Simplify;

Z[s_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, max_ : Infinity] := 
  Total[1/Abs[
     F @@@ ({x, y} /.
        NSolve[Thread[r[x, y] == {s, t}], {x, y}])]];

(dp1 = DensityPlot[
     Z[s, t], {s, -1.2, 1.2}, {t, -1.2, 1.2},
     PlotPoints -> 75,
     MaxRecursion -> 3,
     ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
     Frame -> False,
     ImageSize -> Medium]) // AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]

You can sharpen the edges by rescaling the color function

```
(dp2 = DensityPlot[
     Z[s, t], {s, -1.2, 1.2}, {t, -1.2, 1.2},
     PlotPoints -> 75,
     MaxRecursion -> 3,
     ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[Max[0, Log[#]]] &),
     Frame -> False,
     ImageSize -> Medium]) // AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Revised since the OP was edited to restrict `{x, y}` to reals.

```
Z[s_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, max_ : Infinity] := 
  Total[1/Abs[
     F @@@ ({x, y} /. NSolve[Thread[r[x, y] == {s, t}], {x, y}, Reals])]];

(dp1 = DensityPlot[Z[s, t], {s, -1.2, 1.2}, {t, -1.2, 1.2}, PlotPoints -> 75, 
     MaxRecursion -> 3, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Frame -> False, 
     ImageSize -> Medium]) // AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]

With sharp edges

```
(dp2 = DensityPlot[Z[s, t], {s, -1.2, 1.2}, {t, -1.2, 1.2}, PlotPoints -> 75, 
     MaxRecursion -> 3, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[Max[0, Log[#]]] &), 
     Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Medium]) // AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]

Comment: This is the way I originally had in mind. Be careful, $r(x,y)=(s,t)$ can have complex solutions $(x,y)$ which should not be used.

Comment: Wouldn't it be interesting still to see what it looks like 3 ways:   with all solutions, just real ones, and just complex ones?  Maybe superimpose them with different colors.  Looks from the definition |F(x,y)| still real if roots are complex so still get a real function of two variables.

Comment: @Dominic Great suggestion, haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 11):

Using Roman's method to get an array of bin counts, using `Image` or `Raster` + `Graphics` gives better pictures and faster:

```
bincounts = With[{span = 1.72, step = 10^-3}, 
   Transpose @ BinCounts[Transpose[r @@ Transpose[Tuples[Range[-span, span, step], 2]]], 
  {-1, 1, 5 step}, {-1, 1, 5 step}]];
```

#### Image

```
Image  @ Rescale @ bincounts
```

[image]

To change the default color space (`"Grayscale"`) colors, we can map desired colors on matrix entries:

```
Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] & @ Grid @ 
  Partition[Image[Map[#, Rescale @ bincounts, {-1}]] & /@ 
    {ColorData["AvocadoColors"], ColorData["DeepSeaColors"], 
     ColorData["SolarColors"], Blend[{Black, Red, White}, #] &}, 2]
```

[image]

We can also use [`ImageMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMultiply.html):

```
Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] & @ Grid @
 Partition[ImageMultiply[Image[Rescale @ bincounts], #] & /@ 
  {Red, Yellow, Green, Magenta}, 2]
```

[image]

#### Raster + Graphics

```
Graphics @ Raster @ Rescale @ bincounts
```

[image]

With `Raster` we can use the option `ColorFunction` with built-in and custom color functions:

```
Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] & @ Grid @ 
 Partition[Graphics[Raster[Rescale@bincounts, ColorFunction -> #]] & /@ 
   {ColorData["AvocadoColors"], ColorData["DeepSeaColors"], 
    ColorData["SolarColors"], Blend[{Black, Red, White}, #] &}, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice visualizations. Is there a way to limit the 'plot range' in the sense that all values above $z_{max}$ are white using `Image` or `Raster`?

Comment: @fwgb, maybe you can use `Clip` or `Threshold`  on `bincounts` matrix: e.g., `Image[Map[ColorData["SolarColors"],  1 - Threshold[1 - Rescale@bincounts, {"Hard", .8}], {-1}]]` or `Image[Map[ColorData["SolarColors"], 
  Clip[Rescale@bincounts, {0, .2}, {0, 1}], {-1}]]`

Comment: Very cool! To gain some speed you can reduce `span` to 1.72 without missing any points in the $[-1,1]\otimes[-1,1]$ square.

Answer (score 7):

> The question is how to plot the following 'implicit' function efficiently and sharp in Mathematica?

I am entirely sure that the code below is not what OP wants, but this question did make me to write a document describing an elaborated approach of using several types of Machine Learning (ML) workflows. See
[this post](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2020/12/21/generation-of-random-bethlehem-stars/)
or
[this flow chart](https://github.com/antononcube/SimplifiedMachineLearningWorkflows-book/raw/master/Part-3-Example-Applications/Diagrams/Generation-of-Random-Bethlehem-Stars/Generation-of-Random-Bethlehem-Stars-flow-chart.png)
.

This code and results are from the "Simplistic approach" section of the post (it is better to try it in a new notebook):

```
ResourceFunction["DarkMode"][True]
lsStarReferenceSeeds = 
  DeleteDuplicates@{2021, 697734, 227488491, 296515155601, 328716690761, 
    25979673846, 48784395076, 61082107304, 63772596796, 128581744446, 
    254647184786, 271909611066, 296515155601, 575775702222, 595562118302, 
    663386458123, 664847685618, 680328164429, 859482663706};
Multicolumn[
 Table[BlockRandom[
    ResourceFunction["RandomMandala"]["RotationalSymmetryOrder" -> 2, 
     "NumberOfSeedElements" -> Automatic, 
     "ConnectingFunction" -> FilledCurve@*BezierCurve], RandomSeeding -> rs], {rs, lsStarReferenceSeeds}] /. GrayLevel[0.25`] -> White, 6, 
 Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

Here is a link to the corresponding [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/antononcube/Published/Generation-of-Random-Bethlehem-Stars.nb).

Comment: Wow, I learned lots of new things from your answer.

Comment: @fwgb Thanks, good to hear!

Comment: @fwgb Please note the first random seed.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my surface plot of the star showing analytically the magnitude of F(s,t).  Note in particular I am summing both real and complex roots.  Maybe could use the height to then color-code the 2D plots above.

```
r[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] // Simplify
theF[{x_, 
   y_}] := (33 + 24 x^4 - 116 y^2 + 96 y^4 - 78 x^2 + 96 x^2 y^2)/25
mySumFun[s_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := Module[{mySol},
   mySol = {x, y} /. 
     NSolve[{1/5 x (-3 + 2 x^2 + 4 y^2) == s, 
       1/5 y (-11 + 4 x^2 + 8 y^2) == t}, {x, y}];
   Plus @@ ((1/Abs[theF[#]]) & /@ mySol)
   ];
p1 = Plot3D[mySumFun[s, t], {s, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> 20, 
  ClippingStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},PlotPoints->100]

GraphicsRow[{p1, p1}]
```

[image]

And here is the under-side which looks more like a star.  Might be a challenge to remove the four corners and reveal only the imbedded star-shape.
[image]

**Update:**
My method to extract the star-shape is to define a BoundaryMeshRegion that I can pass to Plot3D.  In order to do this, I first create a color-coded root-map of the region:  LightGreen:  One real root, DarkGreen: Three real roots, Brown:  Five real roots.  As you can see in the plot, this gives an easy way to delimit the region:  Simply go through the array and pick out where the lightgreen changes to darkgreen.  This will then give the boundary of the star-shape.

```
mySumFun[s_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := Module[{mySol},
   mySol = {x, y} /. 
     NSolve[{1/5 x (-3 + 2 x^2 + 4 y^2) == s, 
       1/5 y (-11 + 4 x^2 + 8 y^2) == t}, {x, y}];
   Plus @@ ((1/Abs[theF[#]]) & /@ mySol)
   ];

myCountFun[{s_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ}] := Module[{mySol},
   mySol = {x, y} /. 
     NSolve[{1/5 x (-3 + 2 x^2 + 4 y^2) == s, 
       1/5 y (-11 + 4 x^2 + 8 y^2) == t}, {x, y}];
   {{s, t}, Count[mySol, {x_, y_} /; Element[x, Reals]]}
   ];

matrixSize = 100;

xMin = -1.;
xMax = 1.;
yMin = -1.;
yMax = 1.;

plotRange6 = {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}};
pointData = 
  Array[{#2, #1} &, {matrixSize, 
    matrixSize}, {{yMin, yMax}, {xMin, xMax}}];

myTable = Table[
   myCountFun[pointData[[i, j]]],
   {i, 1, matrixSize}, {j, 1, matrixSize}];

points1 = {};
i = 0;
While[i < matrixSize,
  i++;
  loc = FirstPosition[myTable[[i]], {{_, _}, 3}] // First;
  If[loc != "NotFound",
   AppendTo[points1, myTable[[i, loc, 1]]];
   ];
  ];

points2 = {};
i = 0;
While[i < matrixSize,
  i++;
  loc = FirstPosition[myTable[[i]], {{_, _}, 3}] // First;
  If[loc != "NotFound",
   thePoint = {-myTable[[i, loc, 1, 1]], myTable[[i, loc, 1, 2]]};
   AppendTo[points2, thePoint];
   ];
  ];



 comboPoints = Join[points1, Reverse@points2];
    regionRange = Range[Length@comboPoints];
    myBoundary = 
      BoundaryMeshRegion[comboPoints, Line@(AppendTo[regionRange, 1])];
colorDataRules = {1 -> RGBColor[
   0.7725490196078432, 0.8509803921568627, 0.7333333333333333], 
  2 -> RGBColor[
   0.8117647058823529, 0.22745098039215686`, 0.8549019607843137], 
  3 -> RGBColor[
   0.3764705882352941, 0.6313725490196078, 0.5843137254901961], 
  4 -> RGBColor[
   0.7294117647058823, 0.7137254901960784, 0.7058823529411764], 
  5 -> RGBColor[
   0.8431372549019608, 0.5882352941176471, 0.3411764705882353]}
starRootMap = 
 ArrayPlot[myTable[[All, All, 2]], ColorRules -> colorDataRules, 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic, DataRange -> plotRange6, ImageSize -> 800, 
  Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> White, PlotLabel -> Style["Root Map", 16]]
comboPoints = Join[points1, Reverse@points2];
regionRange = Range[Length@comboPoints];
myBoundary = 
  BoundaryMeshRegion[comboPoints, Line@(AppendTo[regionRange, 1])];
boundaryMesh = 
 Show[myBoundary, Axes -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["BoundaryMeshRegion", 16]]
```

[image]

I next shade the star with a chrome color with Specularity of 1 and place it in a black background with a few extra far-distant stars:

```
myColor = RGBColor[0.6667, 0.6627, 0.6784]
p1C = Plot3D[mySumFun[s, t], {s, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 9}}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{s, t}, RegionMember[myBoundary, {s, t}]], 
  PlotStyle -> {myColor, Specularity[White, 1]}, Mesh -> None, 
  Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None
  ]

backGroundStars = 
  Table[Graphics3D@{Specularity[White, 5], myColor, 
     Sphere[{RandomReal[{-5, 5}], RandomReal[{-5, 5}], 
       RandomReal[{10, 15}]}, RandomReal[{0.001, 0.02}]]}
   , {250}];
Show[{p1C, backGroundStars}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {0, 20}}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

Note:  I too realize this is not what the OP desired but still I learned a lot working on this.  As my final version, I learned I could compose my star with another picture, preferably the dunes of Bethlehem.  So that I next found a stock picture and composed my star of what I thought would be an idealized version for the three wise men to follow using the following code:

```
ImageCompose[image1, star, {920, 300}]
```

Note I can offset the star anywhere on the background with the third parameter so did so in the direction of the sunrise:

[image]

Comment: Would be interesting to compare the contribution of real and complex roots.

Comment: Yes.  Maybe color code:  blue for all real, red for 1 real, 4 (conjugate) complex, yellow for three real two complex.l

Comment: Interesting that there are never 2 and 4 roots, always an odd number.

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete solution but something to share nonetheless. Enjoy.

Rather than trying to invert the nasty polynomials, using ContourPlot functionality to generate points.

More work required but feel free to use. I am not in search of the bounty.

```
F[x_, y_] := (33 + 24 x^4 - 116 y^2 + 96 y^4 - 78 x^2 + 96 x^2 y^2)/25

Z[s_, t_] := Module[{},
  ptsmap = 
   ContourPlot[{x (-3 + 2 x^2 + 4 y^2)/5 == s, 
     y (-11 + 4 x^2 + 8 y^2)/5 == t}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}];
  If[Length[ptsmap[[1, 1]]] != 0, 
   Total[(1/Abs[F[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]) & /@ ptsmap[[1, 1, 1]]], 0]
  ]

dd = Table[Z[ind1, ind2], {ind1, -1, 1, .1}, {ind2, -1, 1, .1}];
ListDensityPlot[dd]
```

Comment: I think you should add a picture. I suggest this because your score is zero, and I happen to know I up-voted. Now down-voting over lack of a picture strikes me as extreme, but it seems that that may be what has happened. Also, if someone just hit the wrong arrow by mistake (it happens...), a new edit allows for that to be changed.

Comment: As written the code does not produce a good picture, the sparsity of the points returned from ContourPlot does not yield a good summation. More work is needed to interpolate the contours.

Comment: Yeah, but (Bad Pun Alert...) consider the optics, man.

Answer (score 4):

Some combination of code by Roman and xzczd gives plot same quality as second plot from xzczd answer but 50-100 times faster (on my ASUS laptop without compilation)

```
r[x_, y_] := {x (-3 + 2 x^2 + 4 y^2)/5, y (-11 + 4 x^2 + 8 y^2)/5};
fr[n_] := 
  Module[{nn = n}, 
   a = Transpose@
     BinCounts[
      Transpose[r @@ Transpose[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {nn, 2}]]], {-1.01,
        1.01, .005}, {-1.01, 1.01, .005}]; a];

With[{array = fr[10^7]}, max = Max[array];
  ArrayPlot[array, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", Frame -> None, 
   PlotRange -> {0, max/2}]]
```

The nice property of function `fr` is that computation time linear depends on `n`.

[image: Figure 1]