# How can I handle graphics or artworks with millions of points?

Tags: graphics, visualization, generative-art

As a hobby, I am trying to use Mathematica and Wolfram Language as a tool for making [generative artworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_art). Generative art techniques may require drawing millions of points, lines, or curves. For example, here is an image of a random attractor produced [by Paul Bourke](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/lyapunov/):

[image: Paul Bourke random attractor]

Because Mathematica (I believe) uses vector graphics, dealing with millions of primitives quickly becomes an issue. For example, the following graphic, which consists of nearly a million points, takes 22 seconds to render on my machine.

[image: Random attractor]

```
stroke = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 3 Pi, .01}] // Point;
 Translate[stroke, #] & /@
  RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {1000, 2}] // Graphics
```

This particular example could be improved by using `Rasterize` on the stroke, but what if one wants to (understandably) vary each stroke that is drawn? Is there a convenient way to handle the creation of such works in Mathematica?

Also see [this example attractor from the demonstrations project](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PeterDeJongAttractors/), which runs very slowly on my machine with only 150,000 points.

Comment: You don't need to map `Translate[]` in your specific example: `Graphics[Translate[Point[Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 3 Pi, .01}]], RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {1000, 2}]]]`

Comment: As for attractors, have you already seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50839)?

Comment: Ah thanks, @J.M. - I've been looking to credit that reference for a long time, and could not find it!

Comment: @J.M. This is link very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you note, dealing with millions of points in `Graphics` will be slow to render. The usual approach for dealing with strange attractors of this sort, is to bin the resulting points and color according to the 'hits'. This can be done easily using `BinCounts`, e.g. for the DeJong attractor:

```
naiveDeJong[{x_, y_}, {a_, b_, c_, d_}] :=
 {Sin[a y] - Cos[b  x], 
  Sin[c x] - Cos[d  y]}

Log[(BinCounts[
     NestList[
      naiveDeJong[#, {1.641, 1.902, 0.316, 1.525}] &, {1., 1.}, 
      10^5], {-2, 2, 0.005}, {-2, 2, 0.005}] + 1)] // ArrayPlot
```

The iterator is quite slow, and will also run into memory problems as you'll need to store all those points and then bin them. Instead, one can compile the iterator and bin along the way:

```
dejongCompiled = 
 Compile[{{xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {ymin, _Real}, {ymax, _Real}, \
{delta, _Real}, {itmax, _Integer}, {a, _Real, 0}, {b, _Real, 
    0}, {c, _Real, 0}, {d, _Real, 0}},
  
  Block[{bins, dimx, dimy, x, y, tx, ty},
   
   bins = 
    ConstantArray[0, Floor[{xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin}/delta] + {1, 1}];
   
   {dimx, dimy} = Dimensions[bins];
   {x, y} = {0., 0.};
   
   Do[{x, y} = {Sin[a y] - Cos[b x], Sin[c x] - Cos[d y]};
    tx = Floor[(x - xmin)/delta] + 1;
    ty = Floor[(y - ymin)/delta] + 1;
    
    If[tx >= 1 && tx <= dimx && ty >= 1 && ty <= dimy, 
     bins[[tx, ty]] += 1],
    {i, 1, itmax}];
   
   bins],
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  (*,CompilationTarget\[RuleDelayed]"C"*)]

ArrayPlot[
 Log[dejongCompiled[-2., 2., -2., 2., 0.005, 10000000, 1.641, 1.902, 
    0.316, 1.525] + 1], Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 500, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][1 - #] &)]
```

[image]

Code credit for the above is due to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50843/41179)