# ListDensityPlot3D does not antialias axes

Tags: plotting, bugs, graphics3d

I sent a bug-report to Wolfram and the case number is [CASE:3454878]

---

I'm on Linux with *Mathematica* 10.3 and I have my 3D graphics output set to the highest "Antialiasing Quality". It works fine for `Plot3D`

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but in a `ListDensityPlot3D` the axes and the box show step-artifacts

```
data = Table[Sin[x] Cos[y] Sin[z], 
  {z, -5, 5, 0.1}, {y, -5, 5, 0.1}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}];
ListDensityPlot3D[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same happens for `Raster3D` objects in general or when I combine `Raster3D` with a smoothed 3d plot.

```
Graphics3D[{Raster3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5}]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I can confirm this behavior in MMA 10.3 on Win7-64, also with antialising set to max. One step further even: the axes are antialiased correctly (no step artifacts) while I rotate the plot with the mouse; when I let go, however, they go back to the situation shown here. PS: it may be useful to add the code that produced your figures.

Comment: @MarcoB This is odd. For me it is always the other way around. While I'm rotating, the plot and the axes are not antialiased and the moment I release the graphics it jumps to it's full beauty. It's just not working for `ListDensityPlot3D`.

Comment: Same on OS X.  In general, having a Raster3D in the graphics prevents antialiasing.  Are you sure it's a bug?  Doing volume rendering might impose limitations on antialiasing.  Maybe it's just a performance-related choice. Rotating these is pretty sluggish on my machine.

Comment: You can try this if you're exporting figures for publication http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200/12

Comment: @Szabolcs I see your point, but the weird thing I was trying to point out is that the axes seem to be properly antialiased *while rotating the plot* (which indeed is very sluggish), but not when the user is not interacting with it. Here is an animated gif of what I see: [image](http://i.imgur.com/Tr5nhAF.gifv)

Comment: @MarcoB Interesting ... on OS X they're not antialiased even while rotating.