# Export 3D plot with antialiasing

Tags: visualization

I'm trying to save the following plot to PNG with 4x antialiasing

```
good = Plot3D[Abs[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, 
  Ticks -> None]

is = 400;
Export["good.png", 
 Rasterize[good, ImageSize -> is, RasterSize -> 4*is]]
```

It looks good in my notebook (left picture) but the resulting PNG is washed out (right picture), any tips?
[image]

Comment: For your specific case `MeshStyle -> Thick` in the initial `Plot3D` should fix it.

Comment: But then the boxes are also too thin. I see that question from 2012 ran into same problem -- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198/antialiasing-in-3d/200 @Szabolcs