# Rasterization problem in version 11.3.0 that was not in 8.0.1

Tags: export, rasterize, version-11.3

I am running MacOS 10.11.5 and I have recently upgraded from Mathematica version 8.0.1 to version 11.3.0. I created the animation for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3403751) on Mathematics using the Mathematica code

```
f[x_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {(t (1 - t))^(3/2) Cos[2 Pi s], t, (t (1 - t))^(3/2) Sin[2 Pi s]}, 
    {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, 
    Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
    Mesh -> 
      {15, {1/1200, 1/12, 2/12, 3/12, 4/12, 5/12, 6/12, 7/12, 8/12, 9/12, 10/12, 11/12}}, 
    ViewVector -> {{10 Cos[x], 10 Sin[x] + 1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0}}, 
    ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
    ViewAngle -> 1/36, 
    ImageSize -> {400, 100}, 
    PlotTheme -> {"Classic"}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Thickness[1/144]]]
```

The `PlotTheme -> {"Classic"}` is ignored in 8.0.1, but is needed in 11.3.0 to get the same lighting and color scheme.

Under 8.0.1, I exported the GIF animation with

```
Export["potatoes8.gif", Table[f[Pi k/32], {k, 0, 31}], "GraphicsList",
  "DisplayDurations" -> .05]
```

[image]

and under 11.3.0, I exported the GIF animation with

```
Export["potatoes11.gif", Table[f[Pi k/32], {k, 0, 31}], "GraphicsList", 
  "DisplayDurations" -> .05, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image]

The output from 11.3.0 is much worse than that from 8.0.1.  The MeshStyle option in the code above was added to try to make the mesh thicknesses similar, as was the PlotStyle option for the lighting.

I have tried different Thicknesses for the MeshStyle, but those that give unbroken mesh lines, give lines that are way too thick.

---

An interesting thing is that under 8.0.1, in the Notebook, the rendered image and the rasterized image look identical:

[image]

However, under 11.3.0, in the Notebook, the rendered image is at a higher resolution than under 8.0.1 (this is a good thing), but the rasterized image looks worse than under 8.0.1 (and at the same resolution):

[image]

It would be great to get the higher resolution images from 11.3.0 in the animation, but I would be happy if the animation under 11.3.0 were at least as good as that under 8.0.1.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what might be done to improve the rasterization quality under 11.3.0?

---

**Update**

Using the `antialias` function supplied by halirutan,

`antialias[g_, n_:3] := 
 ImageResize[Rasterize[g, "Image", ImageResolution -> n 72], Scaled[1/n]]`

I was able to get much better results and also reduce the mesh thickness with `MeshStyle -> Directive[Thickness[1/300]]`. However, this exposed a limitation in the surface rendering (the subdivisions of the surface were quite visible) that I was able to remedy by setting `PlotPoints->120`.

Here is the result of

`Export["potatoes11.gif", 
 Table[antialias[f[Pi k/32], 10], {k, 0, 31}], "GraphicsList", 
 "DisplayDurations" -> .05, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]`

[image]

Note that with a scale of 8 or less in the `antialias` function, the images were still bad, but with 9 or more, they suddenly became much better.

Why this extra machination needs to be added to the basic `Export`, which used to work just fine, might still be considered a bug in Mathematica 11.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you go to **Edit | Preferences | Appearance | Graphics** and crank the slider for "Antialiasing Quality" up to highest quality?

Also, you might want to consider trying the `antialias` functions given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1550/187) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200/187). Those posts might contain additional helpful information about the topic.

When you do this, it's easy to get something like this

[image]

Comment: The slider was already at the highest and I was getting what I posted. I used your `antiaiias` function with a scale of 10 and got much better results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running V11.5.0 on MacOS 1013.4 and I get the same results as you with the default setting for `Rasterize`, but if change them with options, I can get a high quality rasterization

```
f[0]
```

[image: vector_image]

```
Rasterize[f[0],
  RasterSize -> 800, ImageSize -> Automatic, ImageResolution -> 800]
```

[image: raster_image]

Comment: (+1) I tried those values, but the image came out even worse on my machine. However, when I used the `antialias` function from halirutan's answer, with a magnification/reduction factor of 10, it worked.