# CUDALink not working on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-os-x, cudalink

On my MacBook Pro, I have a [CUDA enabled video card](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), yet *Mathematica* does not seem to recognize this. For example, following the [`CUDALink` Setup](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Setup.html), I get

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[]
(* False *)
CUDADriverVersion[] 
(* CUDADriverVersion::nodriv message raised. *)
```

Additionally, according to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Reference.html#1803279895), my card is not listed, despite NVidia saying otherwise.

How do I convince *Mathematica* that my card supports CUDA?

Comment: I think this'll need an update for v9.  I have CUDA working with v8 but not v9.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have not tried it with 9. Will have to do that this weekend ...

Comment: It turns out that the problem was that v9 tried to use the resources downloaded for v8, but the binaries are incompatible.  I couldn't figure out how to remove the resource packet, so I removed the `Library/Mathematica` directory entirely, let Mathematica 9 re-download the CUDA resources, and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer, in this case, is updating the CUDA driver manually. Finding the driver, though, is non-trivial. For instance, this [page](http://www.geforce.com/drivers) says that there are no drivers available for the mac. To find the CUDA drivers, you need to find the [Developer Zone](http://developer.nvidia.com/), and go to the [CUDA downloads page](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Interestingly enough, the [Getting Started Documentation (pdf)](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Getting_Started_Windows.pdf) is Windows specific and does not include the 300 series in its list of supported cards. However, downloading the CUDA for MAC drivers works just fine on my machine. **Note**: you only need to download the drivers (currently the middle of the three links) to get it working.

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[] (* True *)
CUDADriverVersion[] (* 4.2.9 *)
```

alongside the rest of the tests. But, the proof is in the graphics:

```
data = CUDAVolumetricDataRead[
        FileNameJoin[{$CUDALinkExampleDataPath, "Bucky.raw"}], 
        32, 32
       ];
CUDAVolumetricRender[data, "Width" -> 400, "Height" -> 400]
```

[image: output from CUDAVolumetricRender]

Comment: You have a Mac with an Nvidia card? How did you get it? I'd buy one if I could.

Comment: @Jens I have a 2010 model. It appears that the [current line of macbooks](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro) have AMD Radeons.

Comment: @Jens My 2008 MBP has a CUDA capable Nvidia card. I guess the newer ones don't

Comment: @R.M But, the Radeon's support OpenCL which is baked into the OS starting [v. 10.6](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/OpenCLLink/tutorial/Setup.html#292785331).

Comment: @R.M. yes, but OpenCL is less mature than CUDA, and you have to implement more things by hand (e.g. if you want to use BLAS/LAPACK). Thanks for the info!

Comment: Do you needto download all three packages (CUDA toolkit, drivers, SDK) or just the drivers?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries just the drivers. Do I need to make it clear in the answer?

Comment: Probably better to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries done.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the dev drivers to see whether they might solve my [transparancy problems](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186/transparent-textures-dont-show). Alas, they're still there. Very frustrating.

Comment: @Jens the [15 inch macbook pro](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro) has an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M which is [CUDA capable](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). You just have to download the drivers.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, I bought one shortly after that.

Comment: @Jens Great. I was just playing with this again (on a newer laptop), and I just wanted to let you know that they were still available.

Comment: @rcollyer Are you running Mountain Lion? I bought mine before ML came out and haven't uppgraded yet. However, that laptop is the only one ever that regularly crashes for me. I think it's because of the Nvidia card, and disabling switching hasn't helped. So I mostly work on a slightly older laptop which is completely stable, and sync both using Unison. If ML fixes my crash problem, that would obviously be a big reason to upgrade...

Comment: @Jens yes, I'm on ML on this machine. I have not had issues with it. I have restarted this machine only 2 or 3 times since I got it in July. The only issue I have is hardware: the retina display is blurry to me, so I have to increase the resolution to read anything.