# Textures are not rendered in combined graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, bugs

```
p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]; 
p2 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Black], Texture[p1], 
 Polygon[{{-2, 0, -1}, {2, 0, -1}, {2, 4, -1}, {-2, 4, -1}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
 Opacity[1]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False];
squares = 
 Table[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], 
 Polygon[{{-Sqrt[y], y, 0}, {Sqrt[y], y, 0}, {Sqrt[y], y, 
 2 Sqrt[y]}, {-Sqrt[y], y, 2 Sqrt[y]}}]}, Boxed -> False], {y, 0, 4, .25}];
all = Show[Table[squares[[j]], {j, 1, 16}]];
Show[p2]
Show[p2, all]
```

results in this output for me:

[image]

[image]

However, for others (at least one of whom is a Mac user), indeed the `p2` graphic shows up in the second result.

When I click on the cell bracket, and Save As... PDF, the result is

[image]

And finally, if I directly copy and paste the figure (rather than export), I get this:

[image]

I need some independent confirmation of if this a bug in the Windows 7 version of v8.0.4 and if you have any ideas for workarounds since I need a PDF version of the last figure for insertion into other docs. Thanks.

Comment: I can see the `p2` result with 8.0.4 on Windows 7

Comment: Please only use the tag [tag:bugs] if the unexpected behaviour is indeed confirmed by the community (see [tag wiki](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info)).

Comment: @IstvánZachar: Sorry, now I know the protocol!

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Did the exported PDF show up fine for you?

Comment: On my machine (Win7, *Mathematica* 8.0.4) the output in Mathematica is the first one, and I see the second image when I save it to PDF.

Comment: @texasAUtiger No, it's missing in the PDF file. Notice that even exporting `p2` along has the same problem.

Comment: @Ajasja: Actually the expected/desired result is a PDF version of the 4th image in my original post. So something is being lost in the conversion to PDF.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Yes, that seems to isolate the problem, i.e. it is an issue with exporting the Textures graphic to PDF.

Comment: I can confirm I get the same problem with 8.0.4 on Windows 7. There seems to be a general problem with opacity and textures in 3D graphics - if I go to the documentation for `Texture` neither of the examples in the **Generalizations & Extensions** section work.

Comment: @SimonWoods Could you check [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186/transparent-textures-dont-show) and confirm if you seem to have the same problem as described there?

Comment: I am on 8.0.4. and Windows 7  - I get the same PDF (but not PNG) output but I think the first output is because the two `Show` statements are not in separate cells? In the notebook (and in PNG export) I get the nice-looking last graphic. Since the PDF and EPS versions are not vector graphics anyway, why not just export as PNG?

Comment: @SimonWoods: Neither of those examples in that Texture documentation show up for me as they should.

Comment: @IstvánZachar It is indeed a bug, confirmed by John Fultz, see the link at the end of my posted answer. So I've taken the liberty of adding the bug tag again.

Comment: Thanks @Jens! confirmed bug is a good bug, a dead bug is an even better bug.

Comment: @texasAUtiger Are you referring in your comment to the same experience I reported [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186/transparent-textures-dont-show)?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: yes.

Comment: @texasAUtiger What kind of hardware are you using?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, yes it's exactly the same problem as you describe. This is on Windows 7 64 bit, with an NVidia GTX 550 Ti graphics card.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Windows 7, 64 bit on Intel on Intel iCore i7-2760QM 2.4 ghz, NVidia NVS 4200M graphics card

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This non-appearance of the texture is a known bug that also affects Macs. It can be fixed by providing as the `Texture` only the `ImageData` of the rasterized graphic. So you have to replace

```
Texture[p1]
```

by

```
Texture[ImageData@Rasterize[p1, "Image"]]
```

and then the texture will show up. I modified your definitions a little, in line with what I already said in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7778/245):

```
p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, 
   ImageSize -> 600];

p2 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Black], 
    Texture[ImageData[
      Rasterize[p1, "Image", ImageResolution -> 120]]], Polygon[
     {{-2, 0, -1}, {2, 0, -1}, {2, 4, -1}, {-2, 4, -1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
     ],
    Opacity[1]},
   Lighting -> "Neutral",
   Boxed -> False,
   ImageSize -> 600
   ];

squares = 
  Graphics3D[
   Table[{Opacity[.3], 
     Polygon[{{-Sqrt[y], y, 0}, {Sqrt[y], y, 0}, {Sqrt[y], y, 
        2 Sqrt[y]}, {-Sqrt[y], y, 2 Sqrt[y]}}]}, {y, 0, 4, .25}], 
   Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600];

all = Graphics3D[{p2[[1]], squares[[1]]},
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  Boxed -> False,
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

Note I added `ImageResolution` to the `Rasterize` command to try and make the resulting texture look a little smoother.

The resulting file after `Export["file.pdf", all]` is here:

[image: pdf]

**Edit**

A reference for this bug fix is [this MathGroup discussion.](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/GOWo1s1pLZQ/discussion)

Comment: This does produce the desired result in the exported PDF, but the output of the code in Mathematica still doesn't show the bottom Texture graphic for me. (However, my main concern was the PDF.)