# Exporting Graphics3D is not complete

Tags: plotting, export, graphics3d

**Bug fixed in 9.0.1**

---

When I export the result defined as the variable `pot1` to pdf, the lower contour plot isn't showing.  How do I fix this?

```
potential1 = 
  Plot3D[-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 0.125 s^4,
    {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300},  PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, 
    ClippingStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10, 
    MeshStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral", MeshShading -> {{RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, {RGBColor[1, 1, 1]}}, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];

potContPlot1 = 
  ContourPlot[-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 0.125 s^4,
    {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, 
    ClippingStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Contours -> 10, 
    ContourStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[1], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}}, 
    ContourShading -> {{RGBColor[.5, .5, 1]}, {RGBColor[.7, .7, 1]}}, 
    Axes -> False, Frame -> False];

potFace1 = 
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[potContPlot1], 
    Polygon[{{-400, -200, -2.0*10^8}, {400, -200, -2.0*10^8},
             {400, 200, -2.0*10^8}, {-400, 200, -2.0*10^8}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}];

pot1 = 
  Graphics3D[{potential1[[1]], potFace1[[1]]}, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .7}, Boxed -> False];

Export["pot.pdf", pot1]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to a bug in `Texture`. According the docs, `Texture[obj]` is equivalent to `Texture[Rasterize[obj]]` (and you're understandably making use of that). However, unfortunately `Texture` only works properly when you do `Texture[ImageData@Rasterize[obj]]` instead. This means that in your shortened form without explicit `Rasterize`, the `ImageData` isn't being extracted correctly. So what you should do is simply this little change:

```
potFace1 = 
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[ImageData[Rasterize[potContPlot1]]],
     Polygon[{{-400, -200, -2.0*10^8}, {400, -200, -2.0*10^8}, {400, 
       200, -2.0*10^8}, {-400, 200, -2.0*10^8}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}];
```

With this, the export will work correctly.

For reference, here is a link to an earlier question where this also appeared:

[Textures are not rendered in combined graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7835/245)

Comment: Thanks, I have made additional variations on my plot, but now the exported file looks too dark?  Would you take a look at my follow-up question?  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14905/exported-graphics-texture-to-eps-is-too-dark