# Exported graphics texture to eps is too dark

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, textures

Why is the exported graphics eps file so dark?  It looks much lighter (and better) as the Mathematica output appearing the notebook.

After running

```
Map[SetOptions[#, 
 Prolog -> {{EdgeForm[], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
   Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> #] &[{{0, 0}, {1, 
      0}, {1, 1}}]}}] &, {Graphics3D, ContourPlot3D, 
 ListContourPlot3D, ListPlot3D, Plot3D, ListSurfacePlot3D, 
 ListVectorPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D, RegionPlot3D, RevolutionPlot3D,
 SphericalPlot3D, VectorPlot3D, BarChart3D}];
```

and then trying to export

```
contourPotentialPlot2 = 
 ContourPlot[-3600. h^2 + 0.0297 h^4 - 5391.9 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 
 0.375 s^4, {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, Contours -> 15, 
 ContourStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1], Axes -> True, Ticks -> None, 
 AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], PlotPoints -> 30, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, 
ColorFunction -> "BrassTones"];

potential2 = 
  Plot3D[-3600. h^2 + 0.0297 h^4 - 5391.9 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 
  0.375 s^4, {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, 
  MeshShading -> {{RGBColor[1, 1, 0]}, {RGBColor[1, 1, 1]}}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"];

level = -1.4 10^8; 
gr = Graphics3D[{Texture[ImageData[Rasterize[contourPotentialPlot2]]], 
  EdgeForm[], Polygon[{{-400, -300, level}, {400, -300, level}, {400, 300, 
  level}, {-400, 300, level}}, 
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"];

pot2 = Show[potential2, gr, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5},
  FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> True, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
Export["pot2.eps", pot2]
```

It looks like the first image below in the notebook file, but as an exported eps file, looks much darker as in the second image.  How do I fix this?

[image: Mathematica output]
[image: Output file]

Comment: There's a Background option to Rasterize, I think, which might remove that grey rectangle when set to None. However this problem looks quite complex, with that "bitmap eps" code, so I think Jens has the best chance of helping you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why this happens, but it does look like the natural lighting isn't applied correctly when exporting to `EPS` or `PDF`. It does work when I export to `PNG`. However, for your purposes it's not too hard to work around that: just give the 2D part of your plot a glow of its own which overrides any lighting:

```
gr = Graphics3D[{Glow[White], 
     {Texture[ImageData[Rasterize[contourPotentialPlot2]]], 
     EdgeForm[], 
     Polygon[{{-400, -300, level}, {-400, 300, level}, {400, 300, 
        level}, {400, -300, level}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral"}];
```

The only thing I changed in your code is the first line above. With this, I get the expected output without the darkened shadowing effect on the polygon.