# rotating 3d text

Tags: plotting, animation, text

Is it possible to create a 3D rotating text like this:

[image]

[animation here](http://www.flashvortex.com/3D-Rotating-Text-Generator).

Here is my try so far:

```
text = Style["Mathematica  Mathematica ", 128];
g = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta], rho}, {theta, -π, 
    π}, {rho, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Texture[text], 
   Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
   TextureCoordinateScaling -> True, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   SphericalRegion -> True];

Animate[Show[g, ViewPoint -> {2 Cos[x], 2 Sin[x], 0}], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: my attempt]

The problem is that the text is a texture, and one can't look through it. We can use Simon Woods's nice `filledCurveToPolygons3D` function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24976/1364) to change the text into polygons, but wrapping the polygon to a cylinder seems to require non-geometric transformation, which I don't know how to do.
[image: 3D text]

possible related questions:

- [How can I create a 3D FilledCurve object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24946/how-can-i-create-a-3d-filledcurve-object)
- [Character edge finding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding/638#638)
- [Non-geometric transformation of Graphics3D primitives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16991/non-geometric-transformation-of-graphics3d-primitives)
- [How can I wrap text around a circle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/how-can-i-wrap-text-around-a-circle)

Comment: Don't forget [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/rotating-an-image-along-a-mobius-strip)

Comment: Also related: [“Covering up” text in Graphics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4833/245)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is closely related to [the Möbius strip 3D text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5788) question. Since the extraction of *font curves* through "PDF" export of text is not well-known and it is the specific transformation you're having problems with, let me give you the code for creating this:

> [image: text spins around]

It is possible to get the outline of a font by ex- and importing a text as "PDF". With this, you get `FilledCurve`'s for your text which you then can simply transform to a `Graphics3D`.

The transformation from 2D text to 3D is `{x_Real, y_Real} :> {Cos[x], Sin[x], y}` and can be found at the end in the code. The rotation is done by creating a list of images where I add `dphi` to the angles of the above transformation.

As result you have in `out` a list of graphics which can be used for instance in `ListAnimate`

```
With[{text = 
    First[First[
      ImportString[
       ExportString[
        Style["Ah, gravity, thou art a heartless bitch -", Italic, 
         FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], "PDF"], "PDF", 
       "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]}, 
  Block[{allx, ally, meany, minmax}, {allx, ally} = 
    Transpose[Cases[text, {_Real, _Real}, Infinity]];
   minmax = {Min[allx], Max[allx]};
   meany = ((Max[#1] - Min[#1])/2. &)[
     Rescale[ally, minmax, {0, 2*Pi}]];
   out = Table[
     Graphics3D[
      text /. FilledCurve[_, pts_] :> 
        With[{scaledPts = 
           Rescale[pts, minmax, {0, 2*Pi}]}, {ColorData[
           "IslandColors", scaledPts[[1, 1, 1]]/(2.*Pi)], 
          Tube[scaledPts /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> 
             2 {Cos[x - dphi], Sin[x - dphi], 2 y}
           ]}], Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1.5, 0, 0.2}, 
      ViewCenter -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}],
     {dphi, 0, 2 Pi, .2}]
   ]];
```

Comment: (+1), although I think thou hast misquoted Shakespeare.

Comment: @Jens Hehe.. Here I can only reply [Buzinga](http://youtu.be/zpRQtHjEniQ)

Comment: My education is lacking, I see. By the way, `TextMode -> "Outlines"` can be omitted...

Answer (score 9):

As I was going to post this, I saw cormullion's comment. Anyway, as the [linked answer by Heike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5788/245) shows, this works:

```
r = Rasterize[Pane[Style["Mathematica  Mathematica ", 128],2100]];

text = SetAlphaChannel[r, ColorNegate[r]];

g = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta], rho}, {theta, -Pi, 
   Pi}, {rho, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Texture[ImageData@text], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, MeshShading -> None, 
  PlotRange -> All, TextureCoordinateScaling -> True, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  Background -> Lighter[Orange]]
```

[image: imagedata]

The main point is that you have to precede the `Texture` argument by `ImageData`. This is a bug that is also discussed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7835/245) and the link I included there.

Instead of `Background -> None` as Heike used, I use `SetAlphaChannel` to choose where the transparent regions show up. To control the **width** of the text label, I added a `Pane` wrapper.

Comment: I can't test it properly, as transparent textures don't work on my system, but to get closer to the original you could try using `PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Texture1, Texture2]` with Texture2 being a blurred version of Texture1.

Comment: @SimonWoods Ah yes, I didn't think of the blur effect. I'll try it.

Comment: @SimonWoods It stopped being fun when I encountered a new **bug** just now. It reproducibly crashes with front and back textures when one of them is transparent and the other isn't (it seems). Simplest example: edit my code to `Texture[ImageData/@{text,r}]` (save session first). I don't think I want to mess with that right now...

Comment: yep - another one for the "how to crash *Mathematica*" list...

Comment: @Jens Ah, so that's what was crashing it!  I played a little but with it but gave up without figuring out what was crashing