# Coloring problem in plot3D with transparent texture

Tags: plotting, textures

I need to plot multiple surfaces with textures. Each texture is a matrix plot with transparent background. In this way, we can see the multiple surfaces from the top.

```
L= 10;
m1 = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {L, L}];
m2 = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {L, L}];
mp1 = MatrixPlot[m1, Frame -> None, Background -> None, ColorRules -> {0 -> None, -1 -> Red, 1 -> Blue}];
mp2 = MatrixPlot[m2, Frame -> None, Background -> None, ColorRules -> {0 -> None, -1 -> Red, 1 -> Blue}];
mplt1 = Plot3D[1, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[mp1]], TextureCoordinateFunction -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, TextureCoordinateScaling -> True, Background -> None];
mplt2 = Plot3D[5, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[mp2]], TextureCoordinateFunction -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, TextureCoordinateScaling -> True, Background -> None];
Show[{mplt1,mplt2}]
```

The image has slight red color on the surface, which I want to make completely transparent. After I overlay 50 sheets of this kind, the red color really mess up the whole picture.

Could anyone help me to manage the reddish color?

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, please fix them

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Try `PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[Rasterize[mp1, Background -> None]]]`. `Texture` doesn't understand `MatrixPlot` directly. Alternatively, you can use `Raster` directly from matrix with correct parameters inside `Texture`.

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @kirma You may want to post here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35581/193