# How to speed up Manipulate with Graphics3D

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

How do I speed up the Manipulate of the Graphics3D objects here? It is currently painfully slow, and I'm at a loss.

I have reviewed many other posts and implemented what I could based on them, but it has had minimal effect on the speed. I have tried implementing:

- Reducing the angles used to 10 degree steps
- Memoization
- Dynamic (applied at various levels to various functions)
- Initialization code for Manipulate
- TrackedSymbols option for Manipulate
- Using With (both inside and outside Manipulate for the functions currently in Initialization)

I am building a demonstration of the rotation of vectors through the Euler angles. I have excluded the last rotation because the speed is already so slow.

(Apologies in advance for posting the entire code and the poor formatting here and there, which I've chosen to leave as is so that it can be copied and pasted into Mathematica.)

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{
   (* Size a graphics box to make visualization area constant *)   
   graphicsBox,

   (* Original coordinate axes *)
   origCoordAxes,

   (* Vectors rotated once *)
   vectorsRotatedOnce[ψ],

   (* Vectors rotated twice *)

   vectorsRotatedTwice[ψ, θ],

   (* Plane surface first rotation *)

   planeSurfaceFirstRotation[ψ],

   (* Plane surface second rotation *)

   planeSurfaceSecondRotation[ψ, θ]
   },
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.1]],
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1},
  ViewPoint -> {-12, -10, -5}
  ],

 {{ψ, 60}, 1, 91, 10},
 {{θ, 40}, 1, 91, 10},

 Initialization :> (
   x0 = {2, 0, 0};
   y0 = {0, 2, 0};
   z0 = {0, 0, 2};
   x1[ψ_] := x1[ψ] = RotationMatrix[ψ Degree, z0]. x0;
   y1[ψ_] := y1[ψ] = RotationMatrix[ψ Degree, z0]. y0;
   z1[ψ_] := z1[ψ] = RotationMatrix[ψ Degree, z0]. z0;
   x2[ψ_, θ_] := x2[ψ, θ] = RotationMatrix[θ Degree, y1[ψ]]. x1[ψ];
   y2[ψ_, θ_] := y2[ψ, θ] = RotationMatrix[θ Degree, y1[ψ]]. y1[ψ];
   z2[ψ_, θ_] := z2[ψ, θ] = RotationMatrix[θ Degree, y1[ψ]]. z1[ψ];

   graphicsBox = Sequence[
     EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0],
     Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1.25, 1.25, 1.25}],
     Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {-1.25, -1.25, -1.25}] 
     ];

   origCoordAxes = Sequence[
     Black, Opacity[.25],
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.005]],
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)", Black, Large], {1.2, 0, 0}],
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 0.005]],
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(0\)]\)", Black, Large], {0, 1.2, 0}],
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.005]],
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(0\)]\)", Black, Large], {0, 0, 1.2}]
     ];

   vectorsRotatedOnce[ψ_] := vectorsRotatedOnce[ψ] =
     Sequence[
      Red, Opacity[1],
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, x1[ψ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)", Black, Large], (1.2 x1[ψ])],
      Text[Style["ψ", Lighter@Blue, Large], ((1/3) ( x1[ψ] + x0))],
      Green,
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, y1[ψ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(1\)]\)", Black,  Large], (1.2 y1[ψ])],
      Text[Style["ψ", Lighter@Blue, Large], ((1/3) ( y1[ψ] + y0))],
      Blue,
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, z1[ψ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[ Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(1\)]\)", Black,Large], (1.2 z1[ψ])]
          ];

   vectorsRotatedTwice[ψ_, θ_] := 
    vectorsRotatedTwice[ψ, θ] =
     Sequence[
      Lighter@Red, Opacity[.3],
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, x2[ψ, θ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[ Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)", Black, Large], (1.2 x2[ψ, θ])],
      Text[ Style["θ", Lighter@Green, Large, Opacity[1]], ((1/3) ( x2[ψ, θ] + x1[ψ]))],
      Lighter@Green,
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, y2[ψ, θ]}, 0.01]],
      Lighter@Blue,
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, z2[ψ, θ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)]\)", Black,Large], (1.2 z2[ψ, θ])],
      Text[Style["θ", Lighter@Green, Large,  Opacity[1]], ((1/3) ( z2[ψ, θ] + z1[ψ]))]
      ];

   planeSurfaceFirstRotation[ψ_] := 
    planeSurfaceFirstRotation[ψ] =
     Sequence[
      Opacity[.2],
      Directive[Blue, Glow[Blue], Specularity[0]],
      Dynamic@Rotate[surfaceX2[ψ Degree][[1]], 0, {0, 0, 1}],
      Dynamic@Rotate[surfaceX2[ψ Degree][[1]], π/2, {0, 0, 1}]
      ];

   planeSurfaceSecondRotation[ψ_, θ_] := 
    planeSurfaceSecondRotation[ψ, θ] =
     Sequence[
      Opacity[.2],
      Directive[Green, Glow[Green], Specularity[0]],
      Dynamic@Rotate[Rotate[surfaceX2[θ Degree][[1]], ψ Degree, {0, 0, 1}], 
        3 π/2, x1[ψ]],
      Dynamic@Rotate[Rotate[surfaceX2[θ Degree][[1]], ψ Degree - π/2,{0, 0, 1}], 3 π/2, x1[ψ]]
      ];

   surfaceX2[α_] := surfaceX2[α] =
     ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[u], r Sin[u], 0}, {u, 0, α}, {r, 
       0, 1.5},
      Mesh -> None,
      Axes -> None,
      Boxed -> True,
      Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Blue}},
      PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"
      ];
   ),
 TrackedSymbols :> {ψ, θ}
 ]
```

Comment: Works rather zippy for me - what are your hardware specs? `Tube` and `Arrow[Tube...]` can slow down rendering quite a bit - perhaps simply using an `Arrow` will help acceleration.

Comment: It's smooth and responsive on my 2011 iMac with 12GB RAM, even with PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"... It might help a bit if the box didn't keep changing size...

Comment: Add `ImageSize -> {400, 400}` at end of your `Graphics3D` call. All the shifting is actually making it slow down a little ! and if you do not care about seeing each step, you can add `ContinuousAction -> False` and that will make faster.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I've tried it on two different computers with the following hardware specs:  - MacBook Air, but with 1.8 GHz i7 core and OS 10.9  - iMac 3 GHz  - For a fairly basic graphic, I figure Mathematica ought to be able to render this without sweating so much.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for updating those Greek symbols. How did you do it? (I wanted to do that, but couldn't quickly manage it with LaTeX for some reason.)

Comment: @zentient: see [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/1356) for greek letters :)

Comment: Do you have software rendering (`BSPTree` or similar, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190/131)  activated? That really slows down rendering compared to hardware-acceleration.

Comment: Renders and responds to controls quickly and smoothly on my 2010 iMac running V9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. The current code is order(s) of magnitude faster, a huge difference. For posterity, changing the software rendering option to "HardwareDepthBuffer" made a huge difference. Combining this with Szabolics detailed help below was very successful. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I played with this a bit to try to speed it up.  Usually I don't like touching code that is this long, but your code was well organized so it was easy to see what was going on, and it was easy to remove parts and test them separately.

---

What I did first was to remove all optimization attempts that I was not convinced had any significant effect.  Let's find out what part of the code is causing the slowdown before trying to optimize it.

So, I removed memoization, `TrackedSymbols` (seems unnecessary), `Dynamic` (unnecessary).

Then I changed ψ and θ to have continuous values instead of discrete.  Discrete values were not needed since we removed memoization, and having discrete angles creates makes the animation *look* choppy, even if performance is good.  So now I had `{{ψ, 60}, 0.1, 90.},
 {{θ, 40}, 0.1, 90.}` in `Manipulate`.  Also note that using integers in computations is slower than using machine precision numbers.  Using discrete values had the side effect of doing all computations with integers.

Next, I changed all `Sequence` to `List`, the reasoning being that `Sequence` seemed unnecessary and would cause some additional computations to be done (though I really doubt those had an effect on performance).

Next, I removed `graphicsBox` and related things.  To keep the plot area constant, I added the following options to `Graphics3D`:

```
 PlotRange-> 2 {{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}},
 SphericalRegion -> True
```

Side note: This is unrelated to performance or your question, but I would prefer the `ViewPoint` to be closer to the origin.  The large distance causes the perspective to be so flat that I find it hard to mentally follow the rotation.  This is of course your decision :-)

Next, I removed the separate objects in the `Graphics3D` to see which had the greatest performance effect.  `planeSurfaceFirstRotation` and `planeSurfaceSecondRotation` seemed to have a stronger effect on performance than the other two, so I decided to optimize `surfaceX2`:

```
surfaceX2[α_]  := With[{r=1.5},
    {EdgeForm[None],
     Polygon@Join[
       Table[{r Cos[u],r Sin[u],0}, {u,0,α,0.1}],
       {{r Cos[α],r Sin[α],0}, {0,0,0}}]}
];
```

Now it returns graphics primitives, so I removed the `[[1]]` part from functions that use it.  Another note here:  you had `Axes -> None, Boxed -> True, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Blue}}` in your parametric plot command.  These had no effect at all because the graphics primitives were extracted from the result and placed in a different `Graphics3D`.

At this point dragging the Manipulate sliders updates the graphics with the same frame rate as rotating it with the mouse.  So I assume that at this point the performance is limited by rendering the graphics on screen, not by building the symbolic `Graphics3D` object.  The easiest way to speed things up is to avoid transparent objects.  If I make all objects opaque, the animation is completely smooth on my computer.  Personally, I prefer the looks with everything opaque except the `surfaceX2`, but removing *all* opacity (including from the box) will speed things up noticeably.

---

Here's your code, modified as I described, except for removing opacity (some cleanup will be needed as I didn't format it as well as you did).  On my machine the end result is noticeably (but not very significantly) smoother than with the original code.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{

   (* Original coordinate axes *)
   origCoordAxes,

   (* Vectors rotated once *)
   vectorsRotatedOnce[ψ],

   (* Vectors rotated twice *)

   vectorsRotatedTwice[ψ, θ],

   (* Plane surface first rotation *)

   planeSurfaceFirstRotation[ψ],

   (* Plane surface second rotation *)

   planeSurfaceSecondRotation[ψ, θ]
   },
  BoxStyle -> GrayLevel[.75],
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1},
  ViewPoint -> {-12, -10, -5},
  PlotRange-> 2{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}},
  SphericalRegion->True
  ],

 {{ψ, 60}, 0.1, 90.},
 {{θ, 40}, 0.1, 90.},

 Initialization :> (
   x0 = {2, 0, 0};
   y0 = {0, 2, 0};
   z0 = {0, 0, 2};
   x1[ψ_] :=  RotationMatrix[ψ Degree, z0]. x0;
   y1[ψ_] :=  RotationMatrix[ψ Degree, z0]. y0;
   z1[ψ_] :=  RotationMatrix[ψ Degree, z0]. z0;
   x2[ψ_, θ_] :=  RotationMatrix[θ Degree, y1[ψ]]. x1[ψ];
   y2[ψ_, θ_] :=  RotationMatrix[θ Degree, y1[ψ]]. y1[ψ];
   z2[ψ_, θ_] :=  RotationMatrix[θ Degree, y1[ψ]]. z1[ψ];

   origCoordAxes = List[
     Black, Opacity[.25],
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.005]],
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)", Black, Large], {1.2, 0, 0}],
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 0.005]],
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(0\)]\)", Black, Large], {0, 1.2, 0}],
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.005]],
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(0\)]\)", Black, Large], {0, 0, 1.2}]
     ];

   vectorsRotatedOnce[ψ_] := 
     List[
      Red, Opacity[1],
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, x1[ψ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)", Black, Large], (1.2 x1[ψ])],
      Text[Style["ψ", Lighter@Blue, Large], ((1/3) ( x1[ψ] + x0))],
      Green,
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, y1[ψ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(1\)]\)", Black,  Large], (1.2 y1[ψ])],
      Text[Style["ψ", Lighter@Blue, Large], ((1/3) ( y1[ψ] + y0))],
      Blue,
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, z1[ψ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[ Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(1\)]\)", Black,Large], (1.2 z1[ψ])]
          ];

   vectorsRotatedTwice[ψ_, θ_] :=     
     List[
      Lighter@Red, Opacity[.3],
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, x2[ψ, θ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[ Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)", Black, Large], (1.2 x2[ψ, θ])],
      Text[ Style["θ", Lighter@Green, Large, Opacity[1]], ((1/3) ( x2[ψ, θ] + x1[ψ]))],
      Lighter@Green,
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, y2[ψ, θ]}, 0.01]],
      Lighter@Blue,
      Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, z2[ψ, θ]}, 0.01]],
      Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)]\)", Black,Large], (1.2 z2[ψ, θ])],
      Text[Style["θ", Lighter@Green, Large,  Opacity[1]], ((1/3) ( z2[ψ, θ] + z1[ψ]))]
      ];

   planeSurfaceFirstRotation[ψ_] :=     
     List[
      Opacity[.2],
      Directive[Blue, Glow[Blue], Specularity[0]],
      Rotate[surfaceX2[ψ Degree], 0, {0, 0, 1}],
      Rotate[surfaceX2[ψ Degree], π/2, {0, 0, 1}]
      ];

   planeSurfaceSecondRotation[ψ_, θ_] :=     
     List[
      Opacity[.2],
      Directive[Green, Glow[Green], Specularity[0]],
      Rotate[Rotate[surfaceX2[θ Degree], ψ Degree, {0, 0, 1}], 
        3 π/2, x1[ψ]],
      Rotate[Rotate[surfaceX2[θ Degree], ψ Degree - π/2,{0, 0, 1}], 3 π/2, x1[ψ]]
      ];

    surfaceX2[α_]  := With[{r=1.5},
     {EdgeForm[None],Polygon@Join[Table[{r Cos[u],r Sin[u],0},{u,0,α,0.1}],{{r Cos[α],r Sin[α],0},{0,0,0}}]}
    ];
   )
 ]
```

Comment: Many, many thanks! The code now produces a very admirable, smooth Manipulate, for which I am (and hopefully many students will be) grateful. Your suggestions, plus changing the 3D rendering engine to "HardwareDepthBuffer", made a huge difference. One point of note: when I run your code, I think a non-Graphics3D object snuck into the code, perhaps via the surfaceX2 function (?), which the Graphics3D command doesn't want to execute. Either way, a stellar result.